# retrieve of data from oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I have a table in oracle database with name category and inside this category table i have column c_nm and data  are category1, category2, category3, ......and so on 
I want all this data to store in an array or String on my jsp page.
Example:

```
<%@ include file"connection.jsp"%> // for connecting to data base 
<%! String S1[]= new String[]%> declare a string

<%
rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from category ");
while(rs.next()){
s1[]=rs.getString(c_nm);
} 
%>
```

Is this right coding or should i choose another method to do this?

Comment: What's the issue? Does this code compile?

Comment: Just to understand it right. You got a database named "category" and inside that you got a table named "category" which has a column named "c_nm" with the values "category1", "category2", ...?

Comment: i am not getting all categories in  the array is this something wrong in declaring of array

Comment: Do **not** put SQL (or Java) code into a JSP. And do not initiate database connections from within a JSP. This is really bad coding style.

Comment: And it's important to close your result set when you're done with it.  Use `try (ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from category")) { /* ...process results... */ }`.  (This is called a "try-with-resources block", and it ensures that the result set's `close` method is called at the end — even if an exception is thrown.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your list of categories, You need to loop through your results, and add it to a `List`. You would do a list, because you do not need to know beforehand how many categories you have.

```
rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from category ");
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
  categories.add(rs.getString(c_nm));
}
```

Then you can convert, if you really need to, your list into an array:

```
s1 = categories.toArray(new String[0]);
```

If you are confused as to why I pass a zero length array, please research further: [What to pass to the Arrays instance method `toArray(T[] a)` method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727627/what-to-pass-to-the-arrays-instance-method-toarrayt-a-method).

Other things to be careful for:

- Java is case sensitive, `S1` is not the same as `s1`, see your `%!` section.
- not `s1[]=` but just simply `s1=` - see [How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java)
- you need to specify the size of the array when creating one... that is `= new String[10]` vs `new String []`
- I believe that statements in your <%! ... %> still need to end with a semicolon (`;`).

Anyway with all those corrections, it should be probably be something like this:

```
<%! String [] s1 = new String[0]; %>
```

We could have assigned null instead, but I do not know if the rest of the code will be ok. This seemed just the most prudent thing to do for now.

Now also, because you are using `List` and `ArrayList`, you will require [import sections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/page_directive.htm) for it:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
```

Then if you actually want to do something with those categories, you would want to write something similar to this:

```
<% for (String category:categories) { %>
<p><%=category%></p>
<% } %>
```

Note that I did not even use `s1` or `S1` (whatever you called the native array), instead I used the `categories` `List` directly (so there is really no need to do the conversion).

Note that there is much to be said about the solution I provided you, but I though it is the simplest one that directly answers to your questions.