# Java autoboxing rules

Tags: java, autoboxing

I am a java novice and so confused by the following example. Is it okay to think that "==" sign will compare the values between Integers and *"autoboxed"* Integers from int, and compare reference address between Integers?

What about doubles and 0/0?

```
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.*;

public class Autoboxing {

    public static void cmp(Integer first, Integer second) {
        if (first < second)
            StdOut.printf("%d < %d\n", first, second);
        else if (first == second)
            StdOut.printf("%d == %d\n", first, second);
        else if (first > second)
            StdOut.printf("%d > %d\n", first, second);
        else
            StdOut.printf("%d and %d are incomparable\n", first, second);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cmp(new Integer(42), 43);
        cmp(new Integer(42), new Integer(42));
        cmp(43, 43);
        cmp(142, 142);

        Integer a0 = 1000;
        int b0 = 1000;
        Integer c0 = 1000;
        StdOut.println("a0==b0?" + (a0==b0));
        StdOut.println("a0==c0?" + (a0==c0));
        StdOut.println("b0==c0?" + (b0==c0));

        double x1 = 0.0, y1 = -0.0;
        Double a1 = x1, b1 = y1;
        StdOut.println(x1 == y1);
        StdOut.println(a1.equals(b1));

        double x2 = 0.0/0.0, y2 = 0.0/0.0;
        Double a2 = x2, b2 = y2;
        StdOut.println(x2 != y2);
        StdOut.println(!a2.equals(b2));
    }

}
```

The result is:

```
42 < 43
42 and 42 are incomparable
43 == 43
142 and 142 are incomparable
=====
a0==b0?true
a0==c0?false
b0==c0?true
=====
true
false
=====
true
false
```

Comment: Have you tried? System.out.println("eq " + (new Integer(10) == 10));

Comment: answer explained here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unboxing will be happing when `arithmetic operators`, `comparison operators` appear.

eg:

```
Integer a = 10;
a = a+10; //1.unboxing a to int 2.calculate a+10 3.boxing 20 to Integer.
System.out.print(a > 10); //1.unboxing a to int 2. compare
```

But when `==` appear, it depends.

If boxing type appear on `both side`, it will compare `the reference`.But if base type appear on `one side`, and the other side is a boxing type, the boxing type will `unboxing` to base type.

eg:

```
Integer a = new Integer(129);
Integer b = new Integer(129);
System.out.println(a == b); // compare reference return false
System.out.println(a == 129); // a will unboxing and compare 129 == 129 return true
```

PS: In `Java.lang.Integer`  Cache to support the object identity semantics of autoboxing for values between -128 and 127 (inclusive) as required by JLS.
[See source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/diff/4c3f752993a5/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java)

So:

```
Integer a = 127;
Integer b = 127; //cached, the same as b a==b return ture

Integer c = 129;
Integer d = 129; // not cached, c==d return false
```

Comment: But how come does
`Object o1=3;` `Object o2=3;` `System.out.println(o1==o2);` return `true`? Both sides of the `==` here are boxing types

Comment: This happens because of the Integer Cache. Under the hood, the compiler replaces the assignments above with `Object o1=Integer.valueOf(3);` and `Object o2=Integer.valueOf(3);`. The implementation of Integer.valueOf(int) saves certain instances of Integer for re-use. Thus, while the two objects on either side of the == operator are never unboxed, they have the same reference. More: http://javapapers.com/java/java-integer-cache/

Answer (score 12):

Here is the Tutorial for [Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

You can also go through [JLS#5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and [JLS#5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)

`0.0 / 0.0` is `NaN` you can not compare `infinity` at least in maths. I guess that is why this comparison does not work.

From [JLS #4.2.3. Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)

> Positive zero and negative zero compare equal; thus the result of the expression 0.0==-0.0 is true and the result of 0.0>-0.0 is false
>
> NaN is unordered, so:
>
> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= return false if
>            either or both operands are NaN (§15.20.1).
> - The equality operator == returns false if either operand is NaN.
> - In particular, (x=y) will be false if x or y is NaN.
> - The inequality operator != returns true if either operand is NaN (§15.21.1).
> - In particular, x!=x is true if and only if x is NaN.

If you check [Double#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method it has two exceptions

> also has the value true. However, there are two exceptions:
>
> - If d1 and d2 both represent Double.NaN, then the equals method
>     returns true, even though Double.NaN==Double.NaN has the value false.
> - If d1 represents +0.0 while d2 represents -0.0, or vice versa, the equal test has the value false, even though +0.0==-0.0 has the value true.

**This definition allows hash tables to operate properly.**

Comment: thanks~ so a2 and b2 both are boolean value false, therefore equal to each other?

Comment: `a2.equals(b2)` will always return true if both are `NAN` which is documented in the Java doc of equals method.

Answer (score 1):

`==` can only be used for checking if the variables are equal or not if the variables are primitive types. For object variables, `==` is used to compare the reference of the objects. If you want to compare the values of the objects, use `.equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend comparing boxed ints with ==, as it works only for some values.

Comment: I am also reading articles, it seems that for int, == compares the values between -127 - 127.

Comment: Yes. it's kind of a cache. Use .equals() when you have Integers and == when you have ints.