# What is the difference between false and Boolean.FALSE?

Tags: java, boolean, primitive-types

In C++ `windows.h FALSE` is defined as integer which makes sense for some special logic cases, but in Java `java.lang.Boolean.FALSE` is defined as boolean and assigned to false
`public static final Boolean FALSE` and I've seen some people use it.

My question: is there a performance difference between `false` and `Boolean.FALSE`? in general why do people go and `Boolean.FALSE`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html.

`Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` are not `boolean`, they are `Boolean`. They are static instances of the two `Boolean` wrapper objects that correspond to the `boolean` values `true` and `false`.

`Boolean` is similar to an `enum`. The `TRUE` and `FALSE` instances are the instances returned by [`Boolean.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28boolean%29).

As for performance of primitive vs. wrapper; there is no difference that you would ever need to be concerned about. The `TRUE` and `FALSE` static instances help performance a bit, and the javadocs recommend using `Boolean.valueOf()` as opposed to `new Boolean(...)` for that reason. The `true` and `false` boolean values are a little "lower level", but if you are storing them in a `Boolean` (as opposed to `boolean`) anyways it's irrelevant.

You should use whichever makes the most sense for your code and leads to the best readability (and definitely don't start going down the path of thinking of microoptimizations like primitive vs. wrapper types). If you are using a `Boolean`, use the object values. If you are using a `boolean`, use the primitive values. If you are deciding between `Boolean` vs `boolean`, use whatever is more appropriate (e.g. a `Boolean` can be `null`, which may be useful, and also you can't use primitive types for generic type parameters; on the other hand, a `boolean` can *never* be `null` which could be equally useful).

Also note that auto boxing converts the primitive types to one of those two static `Boolean` instances, e.g.:

```
Boolean a = true;
assert(a == Boolean.TRUE);
```

---

As an aside, since you mentioned it: `FALSE` is defined in `windows.h` for two reasons: 1) Because `windows.h` has been in use since C-only days, and C does not have a native `bool` type, and 2) it is traditional Microsoft practice to define data types and values with known, explicit sizes and values, esp. for passing data to Windows API functions across DLL boundaries (beyond the scope of this question) and for integrating with other languages that have different representations of "true" and "false". It is entirely unrelated to the reasons for `Boolean.FALSE` in Java.

Comment: I've missed the "B" i did read it as boolean, that's where I got confused :) thank you

Comment: But that doesn't say *why* "do people go and Boolean.FALSE?". While typing you went ahead and did what I was waiting for which was at *least* addressing "weight". `votes++;`

Comment: @BobbyDigital Of course I don't address that. I can't. Because it completely depends on the situation and the OP did not describe a specific situation. What kind of answer would you expect? Use `Boolean.FALSE` if you are storing data in a `Boolean`. Use `false` if you are storing data in a `boolean`. You could use `false` for a `Boolean` in which case it is autoboxed to `Boolean.FALSE`. There's not much more to it.

Comment: I of course don't expect you to be clairvoyant :) But a simple reason is that for whatever reason a user may require the member functions that are provided.

Comment: strongly agree for "...definitely don't start going down the path of thinking of microoptimizations...".

Answer (score 6):

`false` is a primitive and `Boolean.FALSE` is an object, so they're not really comparable.

If you assign `false` to a `Boolean` variable, like this:

```
Boolean b = false;
```

Java's auto boxing occurs to convert the primitive into an object, so the `false` value is lost and you end up with `Boolean.FALSE` anyway.

In terms of performance, using a primitive variable would *slightly* out-perform using a wrapper `Boolean` object, but your choice should be based on readability and basic design decisions rather than on "performance".

Answer (score 5):

`Boolean` comes in handy when you need a tri-state variable.

Also, you might want to check out this [autoboxing and unboxing tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2012/07/auto-boxing-and-unboxing-in-java-be.html), as well as the [rules for how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559634/java-autoboxing-rules).

Comment: boolean is boolean (true/false) but Boolean is trillean (null/true/false) ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is a very strange question, because `false` is the value of primitive type `boolean`, while `Boolean.FALSE` is a variable of reference type `Boolean`. Its value is reference to the object of type `Boolean` which internal boolean state is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to performance, `Boolean.FALSE` will return a `Boolean` object, which might give you more flexibility to work with.

The primitive alternative takes up less memory

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are unclear with this, you need to know that in Java numericals cannot be implicitly cast to booleans, e.g. you cannot compile something like:

```
int a = 1;
if(a){
    //something, something
}
```

Second, some considerations about performance.
There's always a tradeoff.
When using primitive type `boolean`, performance should be better because you're using a **value** directly, which is either `true` or `false` (obviously, byte-encoded).
When using object type `Boolean`, a variable/field will hold a value, but that value cannot be immediately used, as that value is in fact the reference to an object, so you might have a performance penalty. Of course, this penalty is not significant in most cases. And, if you develop a time-critical application, most likely you are not using Java :). Nevertheless, using object types might bring some benefits in development process and safety in use cases implementation (e.g. it allows nulls, which is critical when you map JPA entities to relational tables and there are bit-typed columns that allow nulls; and this is only one scenario where object type is better).

In the end, be aware of boxing/un-boxing, which allows developers to use `boolean`-typed variables almost everywhere a `Boolean`-typed variable is expected (and the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean` is wrapper class for boolean primitive type, same as we have Integer for int.

Boolean has many methods to play around primitive type `boolean`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean a = null;
if (a) {
   // NullPointerException
}
if (a != false) {
   // NullPointerException
}
// Caution, comparing by reference, meaning 2 Booleans with same value could be different
if (a != Boolean.FALSE) {
    System.out.println("But this one works"); 
}
```