# Boolean.FALSE: When should it be used?

Tags: java, types, boolean

I have been reading the book *[Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/)* by Robert Nystrom and came across the following code:

```java
if (!scopes.isEmpty() && scopes.peek().get(expr.name.lexeme) == Boolean.FALSE) { // <- Focus here
      // some code here      
}
```

In other places where we declare variables, the book uses the more usual syntax `boolean a = false` notation. Stack Overflow has many answers explaining what is `Boolean.FALSE` but there is none stating when it should be used.

Is it a common/good practice to write Boolean.FALSE (or Boolean.TRUE) in the context of equality operators? If yes, then why?

Or,  is it a matter of personal preference and code readability?

Comment: I don't think it is ever a good idea to use `== Boolean.TRUE` just in case the other side of the expression is `Boolean` as deprecated constructor `new Boolean(true) != Boolean.TRUE`

Comment: Boolean is a problematic concept as it in essence has three states. But sometimes Java doesn't allow the use of a primitive or you have to consume an API where the boolean value is sometimes absent or null and then the next best thing is its Boxed alternative. And as mentioned, you should never equal it with the use of `==`. That's only safe for primitives and enums.

Comment: [I think you must go through this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090306/what-is-the-difference-between-false-and-boolean-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a common/good practice to write Boolean.FALSE (or Boolean.TRUE)
> in the context of equality operators? If yes, then why?

It is **not** common/good practice to use `Boolean.FALSE` in general, but there are specific situations in which `Boolean.FALSE` can be useful. One such situation is the code in your question.

Basically, that code means the same thing as `if (!scopes.isEmpty() && scopes.peek().get(expr.name.lexeme) != null && !scopes.peek().get(expr.name.lexeme))` but without calling `peek().get(...)` twice.

If you wanted the exact same results, but without using `Boolean.FALSE`, you would have to write it like this:

```
Boolean tmp;
if (!scopes.isEmpty() && (tmp = scopes.peek().get(expr.name.lexeme)) != null && !tmp) {
   ...
}
```

So, using `xxx == Boolean.FALSE` can have its uses in certain specific situations.

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense now. Thanks for editing.

Comment: I think a cleaner solution would be `!Boolean.TRUE.equals(scopes.peek().get(expr.name.lexeme))`, which is null-safe since the contract of the `equals` method requires returning false for a null argument.

Comment: @VGR that's not going to give the same result in the case of it being null. The original version would return false, but your version would return true (due to the negation operator).

Comment: You’re right.  I guess I assumed that was the intent, but I don’t know that for certain.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean wrapper values TRUE and FALSE are cached, so even though `==` compares references, those references are always the same and `==` works as if value-based.

There is nothing wrong here. It seems likely the value being matched is a Boolean wrapper type and the author is trying to avoid unneeded unboxing, comparing references is going to be much faster.

Also unboxing risks an NPE if the variable getting unboxed is null, the `==` check avoids this possibility (thanks k314159).

Comment: It seems likely that, if the value being matched is a Boolean wrapper type, that the author is also trying to prevent a `NullPointerException` that might happen if he did `... == false`.