# When using == for a primitive and a boxed value, is autoboxing done, or is unboxing done

Tags: java, autoboxing

The following code compiles (with Java 8):

```
Integer i1 = 1000;
int i2 = 1000;
boolean compared = (i1 == i2);
```

But what does it do?

Unbox `i1`:

```
boolean compared = (i1.intvalue() == i2);
```

or box `i2`:

```
boolean compared = (i1 == new Integer(i2));
```

So does it compare two `Integer` objects (by reference) or two `int` variables by value?

Note that for some numbers the reference comparison will yield the correct result because the Integer class maintains an internal cache of values between `-128` to `127` (see also the comment by TheLostMind). This is why I used `1000` in my example and why I specifically ask about the unboxing/boxing and not about the result of the comparison.

Comment: Surely if you ran this code and printed the output you could determine this yourself.

Comment: The question isn't exactly same as the one used to marked it as duplicate :)

Comment: Check this [question - auto boxing rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559634/java-autoboxing-rules). In its answer, clearly, this case has been covered.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one marked. This question asks how the compiler decides whether to box or unbox when comparing a primitive with a wrapper class object. +1

Comment: @Scruffy - Its not that simple. `Integer` class maintains an internal cache of values between `-128 to 127`. So even if you compared `Integer i1=100` with `Integer i2=100` using `==` , you will get `true`. You will get `false` when both `i1` and `i2` are  not in that local cache range

Comment: @TheLostMind, good remark. This is why I picked 1000 as my example, I will add this to the question.

Comment: @Thirler - The question looks better now :)

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30415260/719662

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It is defined in the [JLS #15.21.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

And [JLS #5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> - If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion
>   [...]

So to answer your question, the `Integer` is unboxed into an `int`.

Answer (score 46):

Lets do some examples :

**Case -1 :**

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer i1 = 1000;
            int i2 = 1000;
            boolean compared = (i1 == i2);
            System.out.println(compared);
        }
```

Byte code :

```
....
        16: if_icmpne     23 // comparing 2 integers
....
```

**Case -2 :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i1 = 1000;
    Integer i2 = 1000;
    //int i2 = 1000;
    boolean compared = (i1 == i2);
    System.out.println(compared);
}
```

Bytecode :

```
...
     16: if_acmpne     23 // comparing references
....
```

So, in case of comparison of `Integer` and `int` with `==` the `Integer` is unboxed to an `int` and then comparison happens.

In case of comparing 2 `Integers`, the references of 2 `Integers` are compared.

Answer (score 5):

**Explanation**

1. When two primitive values are compared using == operator autoboxing
   does not take place.
2. When two objects are compared using == operator autoboxing plays
   role.
3. When mixed combination is used that is it contains an Object and
   primitive type and comparison is done using == operator unboxing
   happens on the Object and is converted to primitive type.

Please go through the below link which will help you get understand detailed about auto-boxing with suitable example.

Refer Link : http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/07/auto-boxing-and-unboxing-in-java-be.html