# how to use primitive types properly

Tags: java

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;

Integer x1 = new Integer(10);
Integer y1 = new Integer(10);

System.out.println(x == y);
System.out.println(x1 == y1);
```

The first sop will print true whereas the second one will print false. What is the actual problem ?

Comment: this kind of question has been asked/answered many times... do some google first

Comment: second one has different object so false

Comment: possible duplicate of [java: Integer equals vs. ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is not checking the values rather the objects.

If you want to compare the values of 2 Integer objects you would have to use appropriate methods like [`compareTo(Integer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Integer%29)

Like mentioned in the comments if you want to check for equality only you can use [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2):

The second one is comparing Object Id's.Since every object is having a unique Id it is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

first sop print true because int x and y contains same  bit pattern for 10.

In second approach x1 and y1 are both different object reference variable of Integer type so they are point to different object in memory that's why in second sop you will get false.

if you want to check two Integer's equality you can use

```
x1.equals(y1)
```

it will return true.