# Boolean Value Query

Tags: java, boolean-logic

Can people explain why this code gives its results

```
public class InputTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer w = new Integer(1);
        Integer x = 1;
        Integer y = x;
        double z = x;
        System.out.println(w.equals(y));
        System.out.println(w == y);
        System.out.println(x == y);
        System.out.println(z == w);
    }}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java == vs equals() confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Integer equals vs. ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

Comment: could you be more specific about you question as everybody knowns what is the output. So what is the explanation you want?

Comment: u guys are really helpful arnt u

Comment: Kindly reword your question and explain what is your problem in simple words. If you do not want any more down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
w.equals(y)
```

returns `true` since [`Integer.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) compares the values wrapped by the `Integer` objects.

---

```
w == y
```

yields `false` since you compare the references, not the values wrapped by the `Integer` objects. Since you explicitly create a new `Integer` object `w` (`Integer w = new Integer(1)`) `w` and `y` are not the same objects.

---

```
x == y
```

yields `true` since you assign `x` to `y`(`y = x`). `x` and `y` refer to the same `Integer` object.

---

```
z == w
```

yields `true` since one of the types involved in the comparison is a primitive; `w` is unboxed and converted to `double` (yields `1d`). The same is done in this assignment: `double z = x;`. Comparing those primitives yields `true`.