# if condition is not evaluated correctly

Tags: java, spring

Something weird is happening with the following piece of Java test code. This was written using Spring.

```
ResourceType resourceType1 = new ResourceType(RESOURCE_TYPE_NAME);
resourceType1 = resourceTypeService.addResourceType(resourceType1);

ResourceType resourceType2 = new ResourceType(RESOURCE_TYPE_NAME_2);
resourceType2 = resourceTypeService.addResourceType(resourceType2);

List<ResourceType> all = resourceTypeService.getAll();
List<ResourceType> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for (ResourceType resourceType : all) {
    if(resourceType.getId() == resourceType1.getId()
            || resourceType.getId() == resourceType2.getId()){
        myObjects.add(resourceType);
    }
}

assertTrue(myObjects.get(0).getId() == resourceType1.getId());
```

When I run it, it returns `IndexOutOfBounds` on the `.get(0)` call.

This is weird because the `resourceType1` and `resourceType2` have the IDs inside the `all` list.

This is the result of debugging the code:

Resource type 1 after insert:

```
resourceType1 = {ResourceType@5986} 
 id = 179
```

Resource type 1 after insert:

```
resourceType2 = {ResourceType@5987} 
 id = 180
```

all after `getAll()`

```
all = {ArrayList@5988}  size = 37
 ..........
 35 = {ResourceType@5986} 
  id = 179
 36 = {ResourceType@5987} 
  id = 180
```

This was the debugging data.

Why the `if` condition is not fulfilled?

**Update #1**

Error stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.test.ihbs.service.ResourceTypeServiceTest.test_getAll(xxx.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Which data type is the ID in ResourceType?

Comment: What type does `getId()` return?

Comment: The return type is `long` but the debugger shows `Long`.

Comment: I might sound stupid but can you post the full error stacktrace ?

Comment: I added it. I don't think it has relevant data.

Comment: If id is Long you should use equals method to compare it. Maybe you have type field set to long but getId() method return Long?

Comment: I don't think this is relevant. Java is using boxing/unboxing pretty smart so we can compare a `long` with a `Long` using `==`. I thought about using `equals` and it has the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in comments you can't compare Long using `==` comparator. It only works for values between (-128, 127) and only if they are not created using new keyword. It works because those values are cached by JVM so comparing reference return true.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs) or [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching).

1)

```
Integer i = 100;
Integer p = 100;
if (i == p)  System.out.println("i and p are the same.");
if(i.equals(p))  System.out.println("i and p contain the same value.");
```

The output is:

```
i and p are the same.
i and p contain the same value.
```

2)

```
Integer i = 200;
Integer p = 200;
if (i == p)  System.out.println("i and p are the same.");
if(i.equals(p))  System.out.println("i and p contain the same value.");
```

The output is:

```
i and p contain the same value.
```

3)

```
Integer i = new Integer (100);
Integer p = new Integer(100);
if(i==p) System.out.println(“i and p are the same object”);
if(i.equals(p)) System.out.println(“ i and p contain the same value”);
```

In this circumstance, the output is only:

```
i and p contain the same value
```

Comment: *"It only works for values between (-128, 127)"*--and created not by using `new` keyword.

Comment: This applies to Long too?

Comment: I found the answer on the pages you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"==" always compare the memory location or object references of the values.
equals method always compare the values.but equals also indirectly uses the "==" operator to compare the values. Integer uses Integer cache to store the values from -128 to +127.If == operator is used to check for any values between -128 to 127 then it returns true. for other than these values it returns false .

[Refer the link](https://vijayanbu001.blogspot.com/2016/07/identity-vs-equality-comparison-of.html)  for some additional info.