# Why == does not work for Wrapper classes in Java

Tags: java, integer, wrapper

Why Integer class return false even if value two Integer variables are same.
This happens only when value is more than 127.

```
    Integer a = 300;
    Integer b = 300;
    System.out.println(a==b);
```

The above code prints false. The value of variables a and b are same then why this prints false.

```
    Integer a = 127;
    Integer b = 127;
    System.out.println(a==b);
```

This code will print true. 
Can anybody please explain me why java behave like this.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3637974/1638708

Answer (score 3):

That's because the values under 127 being cached and using same location of storage  for performance reasons in micro level. That's the reason for `true` in second case.