# Why is equal equal (==) behaving differently on Integer and Double in Java

Tags: java, integer, double, primitive-types

Here is my code:
I was checking `equals` method and `==` operator.

I know, if we are not using primitive data types, we should prefer equals method. But here it is behaving differently. Aren't d1 and d2 same references.

```
Integer i1 = 2;
Integer i2 = 2;
System.out.println(i1==i2);
Double d1 = 2.2;
Double d2 = 2.2;
System.out.println(d1==d2);
```

Output is:

```
true 
false
```

Why is it false in case of Double?
Thank you.

Comment: "Aren't d1 and d2 same references."? No, they are two different objects which both happen to wrap the same `double` value.

Comment: Then why is it true in case of Integer?

Comment: Because values between -128 and 127 are a special case.  Try it with `Integer` of value `2000` and you'll see. One sec and I'll find the reference questions.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs) regarding Integer caching.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) is specifically about `String`, but the reference vs value check concept is the same for any class.