# Why does object.equals(new Integer(1)) equate to true?

Tags: java

I am struggling to understand this Koan:

```
@Koan
public void equalsMethodCanBeChangedBySubclassesToTestsIfTwoObjectsAreEqual() {
    Object object = new Integer(1);
    assertEquals(object.equals(object), true);
    assertEquals(object.equals(new Integer(1)), __);
    // Note: This means that for the class 'Object' there is no difference between 'equal' and 'same'
    // but for the class 'Integer' there is difference - see below
}
```

As far as I understand, because `object` is an instance of the `Object` class, the `.equals()` method has not been overwritten, and therefore checks for object equality.

If `new Integer(1)` creates a new instance, then it should be a separate object to `object`. Following my train of thought, the correct answer should be `false`, but only `true` makes this pass. Where is the flaw in my logic?

Edit: I understand that integers between -128 and 127 are cached. If my understanding of the `object` object is correct (as stated above), then this is irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Integer equals vs. ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

Comment: @sidgate No, this one is completely unrelated to "equals vs. =="

Comment: Java `Object` is [polymorphic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Integer overrides `equals` and checks if the underlying `int` is equal to the `int` of the other `Integer` instance, and if so, returns `true`. The reason why Integer's `equals` method is invoked, and not the one from Object, is that the runtime type of `object` is Integer.

Integer is an Object, but due to the overridden `equals`, no object identity is used.

All following boolean expressions evaluate to true:

```
    print((new Integer(1).equals(1)));
    print((new Integer(1).equals(new Integer(1))));
    print((((Integer) 1).equals(new Integer(1))));
    print(((Integer) 1).equals(1));
```

Now consider autoboxing, which reuses instances for values in the range [-128,127]. The following statements about object equality are all evaluating to `true`:

```
    1 == ((Integer) 1)
    ((Integer) (-128)) == ((Integer) (-128)) // in autoboxing range
    ((Integer) (+127)) == ((Integer) (+127)) // same

    ((Integer) (-200)) != ((Integer) (-200)) // not autoboxing
    ((Integer) (+200)) != ((Integer) (+200)) // same

    ((Integer) (-128)) != (new Integer(-128)) // explicit new instance, so no autoboxing
    ((Integer) (+127)) != (new Integer(+127)) // same
```

Comment: So, the comment in the koan `// Note: This means that for the class 'Object' there is no difference between 'equal' and 'same'` is not actually demonstrated within the koan because it's actually `Integer.equals()` that is being called?

Comment: Correct. The runtime type of object is Integer, so you are not calling Object.equals but Integer.equals.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `equals` on an Integer object instance. It is *dispatched at run-time* to the implementation in the Integer class (which regards the Integer equal to any other Integer of the same numeric value). The compile-time type (the static type of the variable involved) does not (directly) matter.

If that was not the case, how would something like this work (where the interfaces involved have no implementations at all):

```
 Comparable<Integer> a = 1;
 Serializable b = 1;
 assertTrue(a.equals(b));
```

Note that *static* methods are "dispatched" at compile-time. That's why you should call them using the class name, not an object instance (which is ignored, can even be null, and the compiler issues a warning).

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I understand, because `object` is an instance of the `Object` class, the `.equals()` method has not been overwritten, and therefore checks for object equality.

You've got this one completely wrong. Even though the static type of variable `object` is `Object`, it remains an instance of `Integer`. That is why `equals()` is directed to `Integer`'s override, producing the right result.

Assigning an instance to a variable of base type, or an interface implemented by the class, does not "strip" the object of its subclass behavior. In particular, an instance of `Integer` retains all its behaviors as implemented in the `Integer` class, even though you have assigned the instance to a variable of type `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

Heard of `Dynamic Method Dispatch`?

When you use a super class reference to refer to subclass object, and if subclass has overridden method, this overridden method will be called.

Hence, though you are using `Object object = new Integer(1);`, calling equals on object will always call `Integer.equals()`.

And `Integer.equals()` checks for integers' equality, not necessarily same same reference.

Answer (score 1):

> If new Integer(1) creates a new instance, then it should be a separate object to object.

That's where you are going wrong. A new instance of `Integer(1)` will be `false` for `==` but `true` for `equals`.

Comment: @Thilo - Good call - removed the incorrect comment.