# Reducing boilerplate in java object addition

Tags: java

I want to write add(), subtract(), and equals() methods for my simple objects, allowing for nulls in fields. I end up using python to generate boilerplate code, and this tells me I am doing something wrong.  What is the DRYer way to write a class like this?

```
package com.blicket.parser;

/**
 * Created by steve on 8/22/16.
 */
public class Foo {
    public Integer bar;
    public Integer baz;
    public Integer qux;

    public boolean equals(Foo b){
        if(
            (this.bar == b.bar || this.bar.equals(b.bar) &&
            (this.baz == b.baz || this.baz.equals(b.baz) &&
            (this.qux == b.qux || this.qux.equals(b.qux) &&
        ){
         return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Foo add(Foo a, Foo b){
        Foo c = new Foo();
        c.bar = a.bar + b.bar;
        c.baz = a.baz + b.baz;
        c.qux = a.qux + b.qux;
        return c;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I was using == for null checks, but it is redundant.  Don't do that, reader.  I am leaving the bad code sample to ensure the comments make sense.

EDIT 2:  Trying to strip out the == checks, if `bar`, `baz`, or `qux` is null, doesn't

```
public boolean equals(Foo b){
    if(
        this.bar.equals(b.bar) &&
        this.baz.equals(b.baz) &&
        this.qux.equals(b.wux)
    ){
     return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

throw `NullPointerException`?

EDIT 3 Electric Jubilee:  Looks like the right answer is

```
public boolean equals(Foo b){
    return Objects.equals(this.bar, b.bar) &&
        Objects.equals(this.baz, b.baz) && 
        Objects.equals(this.qux, b.qux);
}
```

Comment: Short of code generation, byte-code generation, or runtime reflection, there it's not obvious there's a way to do this for the general case.

Comment: @azurefrog: I was fiddling with triple-tick block formatting, and failing to get the result I wanted.  I see that you indented everything; is this the only way to get your better result?  Ideas on why triple-tick failed?

Comment: [Don't use `==` to compare `Integer` objects.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

Comment: Here's the [markdown editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I'm not familiar with this triple-tick.  Perhaps it's not supported by SO's formatter?

Comment: Can you store your bar, baz, qux in an array of integers instead? Then your code can be turned into loops.

Comment: @azurefrog: Looks like it is github flavored markdown only: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/#fenced-code-blocks

Comment: do you know project lombok? https://projectlombok.org/

Comment: @assylias I want specifically named fields to uphold a JSON format on export with Jackson.   I guess I could store everything in arrays until final formatting, but that seems messy.

Comment: @bwarren2 instead of your complicated equals, you can simply `return Objects.equals(this.bar, b.bar) && Objects.equals(this.baz, b.baz) && Objects.equals(this.qux, b.qux);`. That will handle the null case for you.

Comment: @assylias: Oh that's great.  You win the prize.

Answer (score -3):

You should try Groovy, which has support for + and - with overloading operations:

http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html
Chapter 10. Operator overloading

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-pg10255/

So instead of public boolean add(Foo a, Foo b) you write:

```
def plus(Foo foo){
  this.bar+=foo.bar
  this.baz+=foo.baz
  this.qux*=foo.qux
}
```

And then you use it as:

```
  Foo a = ...
  Foo b = ...
  Foo c = a + b;
```

So the right answer to your question is to expand the language an not to generate boilerplate code.

Comment: "Use a different language" probably isn't a viable solution (in the general case).

Comment: Even if groovy is a viable answer, overriding the operator would require the same code as defining `Foo#add`