# How to delete all the same data in an 2_D array java

Tags: java

I am trying to delete all the same data in an 2D array;
for example;

```
0 1 3 4 1 4
0 2 3 4 2 1
0 2 3 2 2 1
```

if the user types the coordinate as `(0,1)`;
all the data that equals to `0` should be `null`;
However, my code will just the delete the data which I typed in.

```js
int a =Integer.valueOf(scan.next());
int b= Integer.valueOf(scan.next());
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<clos;j++){
        if(BubbleWordl.world[i][j]==BubbleWorld.world[a][b]){
            BubbleWorld.world[i][j]=null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: world is an array of...???

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `BubbleWordl.world` is an array of `Integer` class instances, not an array of `int` primitives.

Use `.equals` for comparing `Integer`s:

```
if(BubbleWordl.world[i][j].equals(BubbleWorld.world[a][b])) {
   ...
```

See [Java: Integer equals vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs) for details.