# Getting Max value from Custom ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I've wrote this function in Java:

```
public void calculateMax(Integer year){
    Double max = hoodDataList.get(0).getPercentage();
    if(year == 2006){
        for(Integer z = 0; z < hoodDataList.size(); z ++){

            if(hoodDataList.get(z).getYear() == 2006){
                if(hoodDataList.get(z).getPercentage() > max){
                    max = hoodDataList.get(z).getPercentage();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(max),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Now if I'm correct it should calculate the maximum value of the Percentages and store it inside a variable called `max` but somehow it stops iterating after the second value

Comment: been awhile with java but is z  ++ same as z++

Comment: Tip: always use primitives unless you really need a wrapper object (such as Integer). Try to debug it or at least do System.out.println() on every element. From what I see everything seems to be fine. Maybe you have only two elements that are  `if(hoodDataList.get(z).getYear() == 2006)`?

Comment: From what I see this should work, atleast for the case your List is containing one or more items (otherwise a IOOBE is raised). Can you post your List of items?

Comment: This code works as you expect it should.  What does your array contain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> but somehow it stops iterating after the second value.

I've tested your code, with a custom type stored in `hoodDataList` however I can't seem to reproduce the error.

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
public void calculateMax(Integer year){
      if (year == 2006 && hoodDataList.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.getYear() == 2006))
      {
           double max = hoodDataList.stream().filter(c -> c.getYear() == 2006).
           max((c1, c2) -> Double.compare(c1.getPercentage(),c2.getPercentage())).
           get().getPercentage();
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(max),
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }else
      {
          //do something else
      }
}
```

**side note** - if you're going to use a for loop, don't use the wrapper type (`Integer`) as an indexer, just use the primitive `int` type.

Comment: Why waste 2x memory for that? What if he's got a big list? You can use a filter just like Jacob suggested above

Answer (score -1):

Maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)? Not sure because I would expect that to cause no iterations, and max would always be set to `hoodDataList.get(0).getPercentage()`, but you say it stops after the second iteration.

Answer (score -1):

With Java 8, you can use the following:

```
hoodDataList.stream().filter(i -> i.getYear() == 2006).mapToDouble(i -> i.getPercentage()).max().getAsDouble();
```

Note that `hoodDataList` should be a non-empty `List`, otherwise you can use `OptionalDouble#orElseGet` to provide a `Supplier<Double>` that returns a default value.

Comment: I think the intention of this question is not to use an alternative approach but rather find the bug in the code above.

Comment: He needs to check that the elements `getYear()` is 2006. I think filter would be a good idea, huh?