# Why do nullable numbers not preserve identity?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

In `kotlin` `nullable` values are not preserving identity but equality:

```
val a: Int = 10000
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
print(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // !!!Prints 'false'!!!
print(boxedA == anotherBoxedA) // Prints 'true'
```

Why is this different ?

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation) right next to this code sample:

> Note that boxing of numbers does not necessarily preserve identity

Basically, using the nullable `Int?` type forces the compiler to use the boxed `Integer` type for those variables in the generated bytecode instead of the primitive `int`. So the code sample translates to this Java code:

```
int a = 10000;
Integer boxedA = Integer.valueOf(a);
Integer anotherBoxedA = Integer.valueOf(a);
System.out.print(boxedA == anotherBoxedA);
```

This, of course, prints `false`, since two different `Integer` instances have been created by the two `Integer.valueOf` calls. Thought the JVM has caching for the instances created by `Integer.valueOf` calls, [it only works between -128 and 127](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637974/4465208) - if you run the code with `a` having a value in that range, both comparisons will indeed return `true`.

Answer (score 3):

> `a === b` evaluates to true if and only if a and b point to the same
>   object.

That's not true for `boxedA === anotherBoxedA.`

[Kotlin - Equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Referential equality means that two references point to the same
>   object.

[Document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html), Referential equality is checked by the === operation (and its negated counterpart !==). a === b evaluates to true if and only if a and b point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin , we have two different concepts of equality, **Referential equality** and **Structural equality**

**Referential equality**

We use the **===** symbol which allows us to evaluate the reference of an object(if it's pointing to the same object). This is an equivalent of "==" operator in java. thats why `boxedA === anotherBoxedA` return false(Because they are two separate objects, each pointing to a different location in memory).

**Structural Equality**

We use the **==** symbol that evaluates if both values are the same (or equal). This is usually achieved by implementing `equals()` method in java. 
That's why it `boxedA == anotherBoxedA` it return true