# Removing duplicates in linked list (in ascending order)

Tags: java

My code is working for 1 and 2 digit numbers but not for numbers > 2 digits

```
public class remove_duplicates {

    public static node<Integer> takeInput() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int data = s.nextInt();
        node<Integer> head = null;
        while (data != -1){
            node<Integer> newNode =new node<Integer>(data);
            if(head == null){
                head = newNode;
            }
            else {
                node<Integer> temp =  head;
                while(temp.next != null){
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
                temp.next =newNode;
            }
            data = s.nextInt();
        }
        return head;
    }

    public static node<Integer> removeDuplicates(node<Integer> head){
            node<Integer> current = head;    
            while(current.next != null){
                if(current.data == current.next.data){
                    current.next = current.next.next;
                }
                else
                    current = current.next;
            }

            return head;
        }


    public static void print (node<Integer>head){
        node<Integer> temp = head; 
        while (temp != null) 
        { 
            System.out.print(temp.data+" "); 
            temp = temp.next; 
        }   
        System.out.println(); 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        node<Integer> head = takeInput();
        node<Integer> data = removeDuplicates(head);
        print(data);
    }
}
```

- My output: 281 386 386 957 1022 1216 1232 1364 1428 1428 1428 1428 1501 1953
- Expected output: 281 386 957 1022 1216 1232 1364 1428 1501 1953

Why is it working for 1/2 digits integers and not for 3 digits or more? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `Integer` is an `Object`, use `.equals()` instead of `==`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Integer equals vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto yes and no. See the linked duplicate

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Caching aside, it is preferable to use `.equals()` in case of `Object`s...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto that's for sure, but it's interesting to know why it still worked with small numbers.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Use `equals()`. At `removeDuplicates` function change the line `if(current.data == current.next.data)` by the following: `if(current.data.equals(current.next.data))`

### Rationale

You should **always** use `equals()` to compare a particular **value** of two objects and not `==`. The reason of that is because `==` compares object references and `equals()` compares the value of that object. That value will depend on your needs and you could set your particular comparison criteria, but for native types *wrappers* like `Integer` it compares by default the *number* and not the objects adresses -which is what you get by using `==`-.

### Why `==` works for one/two digits `Integer`?

When the value of an Integer is in the range of `[-128; 127]` Java uses a cache to store numbers, so if a number is in the cache, it re-use that object. So the reference `==` will work, because they are referencing the very same object. On the other hand, if you use an integer greater than `127` or lower than `-128`, it won't work because Java will create different objects outside of the cache scope.