# Multi level list filtering java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am working with classes with multi level depth. I am trying to filter in the inner depth but i am receiving the error

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: Stream<InnerClassName> cannot be converted to boolean
```

The structure of my Classes is

```
class A {
    List<B> B;
    Integer Id;
}

class B {
        List<C> C;
        Integer Id;
    }


class C {                    
         Integer Id;
        }
```

If I have List called `AList`
I have tried doing

```
AList.getBlist().stream().filter(bList -> bList.getId.equals(5));
```

Which works fine. What i am trying to accomplish is filter with values inside `Class C` which could be obtained by `Blist.getClist`

Comment: What is your final output supposed to be? `List<A>` or `List<C>`?

Comment: List<A> would be fine i wanted to check if linked objects with condition exist, if only List<C> is possible it would not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to filter the content of `List<A>` and obtain the same format as output, you can perform it as :

```
List<A> output = aList.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getBList().stream() // bList from a
                .flatMap(b -> b.getCList().stream()) // cList from each b
                .anyMatch(c -> c.getId() == 5)) // equals(5)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code filters in all those 'A' from the `List<A>` such that any 'C' part of a `List<C>` within any 'B' part of a `List<B>` within A matches the given condition.

Comment: `c.getId().equals(5)` can only be `true` when `c.getId()` returns an `Integer`. In that case, it’s preferable to use `c.getId() == 5` which will evaluate to the same result, but would raise a compiler error if `c.getId()` does not return a compatible numeric type (whereas `Object.equals(Object)` accepts anything, even when impossible to ever be `true`).

Comment: @Holger Point noted. Thanks. Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs) which is 8yrs old, need a revisit though?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still valid. When both sides of `==` or `!=` are objects, a reference comparison will be made. The best solution is to ensure that at least one side is not an object. E.g. if the task is not about matching with the constant `5`, but a parameter `Integer matchValue`, unbox it before the Stream operation, like `int valueToUse = matchValue;`, followed by `anyMatch(c -> c.getId() == valueToUse)` within the Stream operation.

Comment: @Holger Why not instead compare objects with `equals` in the latter case? Just because there is no concrete type bound there?

Comment: That’s one reason. Further, the type promotion behavior differs, e.g. how `int` and `long` are compared, or how `null` (on the right hand side) is handled.