# pop() function for stack referred by min not working properly?

Tags: java

I was attempting a question on leetcode and not sure about this anomalous behaviour. I am providing the logic part of the question. Please let me know if any discrepancy is found.

> Question: Design a stack that supports push, pop, top, and retrieving
>   the minimum element in constant time.
>
> push(x) -- Push element x onto stack.
>
> pop() -- Removes the element on top of the stack.
>
> top() -- Get the top element.
>
> getMin() -- Retrieve the minimum element in the stack.

[Link to leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/)

Approach: Using 2 stacks, `values` (with original values in their order) and `min` (with values sorted in ascending order)

```
    class MinStack {

        Stack<Integer> min;
        Stack<Integer> values;

        /** initialize your data structure here. */
        public MinStack() {
            min = new Stack<>();
            values = new Stack<>();
        }

        public void push(int x) {
            if(values.isEmpty()){
                values.push(x);
                min.push(x);
            }
            else{
                values.push(x);
                if(min.peek()<x){
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    while(!min.isEmpty() && min.peek()<x)
                        list.add(min.pop());
                    min.push(x);
                    for(int i=list.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
                        min.push(list.get(i));
                }
                else
                    min.push(x);
            }
            System.out.println("min after push-->"+min);
            System.out.println("values after push -->"+values);

        }

        public void pop() {

                if(values.peek()==min.peek()){
                    min.pop();
                }

                else{
                   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    while(!min.isEmpty() && min.peek()!=values.peek()){
                         list.add(min.pop());
                    }
                       if(!min.isEmpty()){
                             min.pop();
                       }


                    for(int i=list.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
                        min.push(list.get(i));
                }
           values.pop();

            System.out.println("min after pop -->"+min);
            System.out.println("values after pop-->"+values);

        }

        public int top() {
            System.out.println("min on top -->"+min);
            System.out.println("values on top-->"+values);
           return values.peek();
        }

        public int getMin() {
            System.out.println("min for getMin-->"+min);
            System.out.println("values for get min-->"+values);
            return min.peek();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Your MinStack object will be instantiated and called as such:
     * MinStack obj = new MinStack();
     * obj.push(x);
     * obj.pop();
     * int param_3 = obj.top();
     * int param_4 = obj.getMin();
     */
```

Comment: your `push` and `pop` are not constant-time operations since they contain loops

Comment: @mangusta Agreed. Thanks. Still pop is not working on min. Like it has no effect. it just stays as is. Any specific reason for that?

Comment: what is the sequence of operations that you are testing?

Comment: @mangusta - ["MinStack","push","push","push","push","pop","getMin","pop","getMin","pop","getMin"]
[[],[512],[-1024],[-1024],[512],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

Comment: could you also specify the pushed values? (for `push` operations)

Comment: @mangusta - Already specified. Sequence being - [[],[512],[-1024],[-1024],[512],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

Comment: I mean, specify which value was pushed for every push operation, otherwise it's unclear which element was pushed at which moment

Comment: You may want to read about the [Heap data structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper classes like `Integer`, `Long` should use `equals` rather than `==`

1. Use `equals` here `if(values.peek()==min.peek()){`

   Change it to `if(values.peek().equals(min.peek())){`
2. Also `min.peek()!=values.peek()` to `!min.peek().equals(values.peek())`
3. The last thing is you remove the `System.out.println` lines
4. One more suggestion would be to not use entire stack for sorted values and recreate it everytime a `pop` is done on the actual stack.

   Rather you should maintain a single `min` variable and update it if the `pop` has removed the min item. You can find minimum value using `min()` method from `stream()`

You can have a look at the following too

[Java: Integer equals vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637978/578855)

[How to properly compare two Integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515811/578855)

Comment: @ArnavBhattacharya Did this answer help you?

Comment: OK. Please accept the answer and upvote as it worked successfully. Thanks.

Comment: @ArnavBhattacharya What kind of obstacle possibly prevented you from accepting the answer?

Comment: @Cortex - Didn't get you

Comment: I was wondering, since you saw the answer and found it useful .. why didn't you accept it but you eventually did J