# What are the difference between "if(map.get(key)-map1.getOrDefault(key, 0)!=0)" and "if(map.get(key)!=map1.getOrDefault(key, 0))"

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following code-

```
package DP.permutation_in_string;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LeetCode {
    public static boolean checkInclusion(String s1, String s2) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
            map.put(s1.charAt(i), map.getOrDefault(s1.charAt(i), 0)+1);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<=s2.length()-s1.length(); i++){
                Map<Character, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
         
                for(int j=i; j<i+s1.length();j++){
                    map1.put(s2.charAt(j), map1.getOrDefault(s2.charAt(j),0)+1);
                }
                
                if(mapCompare(map, map1))
                    return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    static boolean mapCompare(Map<Character, Integer> map, Map<Character, Integer> map1){
        for(char key:map.keySet())
            //if(map.get(key)!=map1.getOrDefault(key, 0))
            if(map.get(key)-map1.getOrDefault(key, 0)!=0)
                return false;
        
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="ckzviabspcfbabslodcxtzanlsnwbqrozvnfadhtskosxhxaxzwcthvirwivsfuyxgkdvvdmmaoohvnfegkzdajhzibfiuxvsihpseyyiapmgldyojfselzzudzrxcksvfoqoeimyfhnvidryqhhpvjawwpzspcfnvmewnhcbbbwfjifmcuspbrrjyhcusyiuydscwenyicdlfzaoaiudsdyjmhmzwmeaozheiaddevjrrgsfgqnyeoyxfvktctazsfizkynlookeorzmdvtloyfpbqjgzhjvykdthwkuubnbalrddjxpizysaptrinlytecouekkpsfzbjaitckodcdinydtaaakbntwbvrcabylllxtgtkdqfkjggvbrnxnvcsfpcutabvazyeqzitpwhhdpcxaklhbjrcsqzveytzbgoeqnyrbkvkfnlqhrnedjomfmkuadwabnzomgvtdypocbvipryedcxnrcrqwpefqducxxilhpoewlliilidxucjydpahcumngpekrlroftwpbaejfjmohnkulxdglcpcszpyqestonhxskshzmdkikjkeymddyiysmigvqjveocbabhcofwyseytwfgiqmufcqrugwofytxzwwwiwlxdshtamwneosotqbfjjdxmhjkmzcvpmkuumycqzvlmwvjdwkcikyewupwaotrseyomhuykdkohveftgqfoqjcnstlxdasnvimslmuqsqrhvbukyfvpswmlavtxegbcesxgzswwnslxymmrdwmpalcazukvyyotlvwvlishtgbmlznrmcjysjemwqfjgbehnowgjlvtgemlkkdqpxiuqwhqkqdkexoflxfescoblknurkntbpfqfiervqgeiasguycmjoyzyujgzdfjobrswjpxixmadnnkdtazbasmnnlbubokkvomtupdpqwnoddummmqbwbthfhqdgdawdwxlmgvelhefvqcrpxbkgvhyrpxmfivrvkkqfpxjhzqesiqoeanqzpvbgonwptzqgtajoiiphivxtefarwjyoklkxumrndswebdsgiipzrcunpnibmxwlkihnzlswaujflztxxnuhojrpkzldwhnuiizxalawskkvaplopthvzjrbqfwpwjfkzrhyciajdsaeusctnvajuubjiqdqsaqjxtxgxabpdwxzgiedyyeosfdbkairekywkilyksjratftctphompqoomxucysbzrpywjzumoiizklkooilgeapimiixawfgiszfqucihxfrtrwijyeiebudncwnxbnafohhhqaltksafjfegxlbbewetsyrtuxxlngffpcnyfdarqwznsuiuhvqshjpvbiqkxgfwyrkdlorlwgexfinunbfzifxlfufalbkyfdekhupuuflsetpbppaahwbtjpjguygpnavimbbaeikwjxurdxyfgmldgdbkyxzhvwlxzlpnpmzlyosvhngmuqkrvcsabhiahhguxuakphuaptbjfpxybqnlfazkagwlbvzcnzorpymafiwvtkjtilwihwoyelogtpdyipzkurqcghpdqgrfpnmrmahbkbyupxwooblaydongjrlnuhoikoyiexgzlzgonceyhfwypsgypilxcnkdhxvbfddnhvdicolrjyzttrymmcvoyswaszbbugsuuewhewtoxgnrbfqsysjqqcutoikssesxaohxxfxofiguvpgzfkimmqdjuyljlpndapzygidopwxnaetmmpyaqozybbpfqlonebiilvckmtyaommksfcrmdeyjjbjncmpruofaaccnvndkovjugcrzcwkbdhqdiwnvnavnngloshyataygyukrecamzftmeephucmofjgrzsexsprpdkazhmtaepqppgzjmxxzlpbkouqlhqcxdpaslrjrsnfbjvbekpyqsldzhxarpzbbjteudfwfjdipgcdwylorxivwbjkegazpcngzkokygjfnmfeumbetznsxsmyhccurqdzznvhrtawpklrrrbedqzkiczignlaoaiydezgktdecaxwxxecymbuisvhlcjlhmnpjuegnaawfxopvvkxihehquxzlveabigomeptsqbfurytjikpbtsotgfghadilylnimxcsvgtmzjgxjyhabtfawzmomctquctwnolglflghdugeutgdmkitunbkhgoceqyrzvwprotiysaiqcnwxflcjgjqobeskizjqqwihnmxyvbeeufyvouupnyuuyauxtmhtqlbgoacjdkvmuqohbkpctfwxvwlghevsuozrgxkrrrllnvjloeligxvnvzluxlajszgeilxdjaviawhlthtxuclqypgdiwgwrhynmzqghyzeednlmyepgxxvtmjsuprisbgyvcojhculwdkjmpmvueaftiujrmdqptrmlrwdyjtjlznuhftzmffbcqsjemrpjrqxtuxhlnqvckgcuvhswgtxonfljjwnexdafpjzwjdypdfwhwogikkpsvuckmgehcqmdecriamdqsdsxuhsdqenrpifzjnpvrbpvetatbmvsncltabzspzedumeclbxiqnsmdkbqfedikoalfsnxkhewwzyeqxlecfimvdpxdnvrtlxlxzakupknvchursvilyjyfxmvdeojclhjjwxtpqiogsfdnzchrlztvxmibbociiberaevpjmyqxvcicxuwkmyjlgxhvrjdqbjzdctzwidoplkvazhgsdbkavmrpfjgebydmloykqtxocdhcpwrtvawhofvwnohtwodppmcrbhvrvexzijiwgkptntyljvikjlzpjvpxaejfwzyldxrckbzylvhpqmjjeyatmrbcgozvcalcctngwuysjqmkmhjwmyyfxhdjswimahqzptrphtjekkabpgopfdnhwaclxzavftmswadgztxceonrkczurtdvxhabiafyzdbdbyorerekjzgpueihiamlscdndjjgqwdjsmeweqrfpypfrfsciclvrrqchnmtxscbvbbipzingkeopuvlnpqaeqidlpvusbkjhntvxbookqctymjmhqjvsnaiblmnofxphanpxspmkmxmyejooqpytdixgguonbpaipurpwwfqxrrtekvvtpgndabbvjcoxonxciuypxqcfolxirvafnmgsrcrenwyuxfekuqyfdtvhvmonvkstbmvygsbguiknltpixsebxktczniurulxpyxckrtmhpvgqpbvlqwvcqwaocalqtdwomgrjyvryodeikbeeebcrrkugliqgktoohsneynmfafykpmndfgwtpdwfrmicenyntbfyyntlqqrujfioycrhopgiadmsjcycucyuqvzufbvachmlwyfxspzrvkkvkhuykoqrwshzmyypmvosuezpsgtqtecayj";
        String s2="livsugnixbcmmajhinduvzfjzxtzneixibupxfezifaovcbowfayjtlcdsjogjytuczxbwluiktkdyecquebuvkgfobhpiqfbyckfbchvfkdowckrvuiblhbmubugrrovdhbyvevwetlusthiyxgtaqcdfytgbkrnnjifdslzntgnryqcmwkumdvqctymyffanmawobfihsfqmtqvivvouunsexpzcfmiituppwxgjyspyoeuspyystyneoonatbojiufzhhfeakqzeypaopkyscadbkzsnnjewgflysazhwaigicrzeccanemfmrvrdzxtcbuqvjblrynlhbmtkzhtiqnhrfclxovtijwucgvsreirqmhweoazxdyydksrchvizmljhdkekaxbqkleaolqnepijxpwbcxfadfsxswhzmmffsmoiyfosbwjjcgqpexddwizaiqpsaagwxkajdhqeyouihwlfrmnelakembxwcrvwqyaguvqewjczfmfqiqmjbqxcmfrpqoewszkomwckfgrlkannjefxsulbpkpxlvbrgwruvhdonuezoomvnyridrosfzhfvhmqbzdsfvjgfdqvafheuhveaqwrofhgkfobkkevdsqyumzrvapfjypvjsdzaxxwcnsbxasqewmkmucxbgjqntdsvrbndebttkoiznatcjgtgklljurkkdvpbrtbolvgrqwsnuoubhgvtmbakwgvxypndpqtireuvbdxfjcioqqsbfrqahqsfbwfnlkwobnqdbptxrizourrxyjejflgkbcwmrtttqeeqkyzrzdcfakwcfajhjfmcpnsbekwtzgpbwrotgsxopaemsnywoxsqxoyricgosfurfggulchgyoocivnkqytgbroijmaduoywbudtgwugekikebdadoygtmikcficifdcsvritesbvznlbrgbveudwzatarhbehowrrakimocgqyxzedhlqxzxtqloupbwbdvewcbehkmoahoykouhilivtxukqhwmyjjqmfxqybahsubfvnhctudtpxwsnwfmsamavjkqiabzzcqgqssygswavqpdtxfyognqybsogsbkzkktfjqebhitvqnawokacbkfkthqoammdscyvxgaaqyaplexhlwweambfwtylvihpdedshaeluxgthrejkgkvwrtyzpuygqghtlkmpnzkyjiwyuaqijkxttvdsxddfkmgnnlmamjumsbjmjxqkrgncrwyoyetdsmtanoasirkfklcsxukfdebnlbgobwgyqrthzwjbwpxuxmheplqyjaucgrptfewjahejsfypktnpafmlrzekbjqsgthrwbdxttitsqyglsjgnzmscncgvkooxdlxsmmugeeayicndgoagpfckerzuwdphqksijniyckzviabspcfbabslodcxtzanlsnwbqrozvnfadhtskosxhxaxzwcthvirwivsfuyxgkdvvdmmaoohvnfegkzdajhzibfiuxvsihpseyyiapmgldyojfselzzudzrxcksvfoqoeimyfhnvidryqhhpvjawwpzspcfnvmewnhcbbbwfjifmcuspbrrjyhcusyiuydscwenyicdlfznoaiudsdyjmcmzwmeaozheiaddevjrrgsfgqnyeoyxfvktctazsfizkynlookeorzmdvtloyfpbqjgzhjvykdthwkuubnbalrddjxpihysaptrinlytecouekkpsfzbjaitckodcdinydtaaakbntwbvrcasylllxtgtkdqfkjggvbanxnvcsfphutabvazyeqzitpwhhdpcxaklhbjrcsqzveytzbgoeqnyrbkvkfnlqhrnedjomfmkuadwabnzomgvtdypocbvipryedcxnrcrqwpefqducxxilhpoewlliilidxucjydpahcumagpekrlroftwpbaejfjmohnkulxdglcpcszpyqestonhxskshzmdkikjkeymdfyiysmigvqjveocbabhcofwyseytwfgiqmufcqrugwofytxzwwwiwlxdshtamwneosotqbfjjdxmhjkmzcvpmkuumycqzvlmwvjdwkcityewupwaotrseyomhuykdkohveftgqfoqjcnstlxdasnvimslmuqsqrhvbukyfvpswmlavtxegbcesxgzswwnslxymmrdwmpalcazukvyyotlvwvlishtgbmlznrmcjysjemwqfjgbehnowgjlvtgemlkkdqpxiuqwhqkqdkexoflxfescoblknurkntbpfqfiervqgeiesguycmjoyzyujgzdfjobrswjpxixmadnnkdtazbasmnnlbubokkvomtupdpqwnoddummmqbwbthfhqdgdawdwxlmgvelhefvqcrpxbkgvhyrpxmfivrvkkqfpxjhzqesiqoeanqzpvbgonwptzqgtajoiiphivxtefarwjyoklkxumrndswebdsghipzrcunpnibmxwlkihnzlswaujflztxxnuhojrpkzldwhnuiizxalawskkvaplopthvzjrbqfwpwjfkzrhyciajdsaeusctnvajuubjiqdqsaqjxtxgxabpdwxzgiedyyeosfdbkrirekywkilyksjratftctphompqoomxucysbzrpywjzumoiizklkooilgeapimiixawfgiszfqucihxfrtrwijyeiebudncwnxbnafohhhqaltksafjfegxlbbewetsyrtuxxlngffpcnyfdarqwznsuiuhvqshjpvbiqkxgfwyrkdlorlwgexfinunbfzifxlfufalbkyddekhupuuflsetpbppaahwbkjpjguygpnavimbbaeikwjxurdxyfgmldgdbkyxzhvwlxzlpnpmzlyosvhngmuqkrvcsabhiahhguxuakphuaptbjfpxybqnlfazkagwlbvzcnzorpymafiwvtkjtilwihwoyelogtpdyipzkurqcghpdqgrfpnmrmahbkbyupxwooblaydongjrlnuhoikoyiexgzlzgonceyhfwypsgypilxcnkdhxvbfddnhvdicolrjyzttrymmcvoyswaszbbugsuuewhawtoxgnrbfqsysjqqcutoikssesxaohxxfxofiguvpgzfkimmqdjuyljlpndapzygidopwxnaetmmpyaqozybbpfqlonebiilvckmtyaommksfcrmdeyjjbjncmpruofaaccnvndkovjugcrzcwkbdhqdiwnvnavnngloshyataygyukrecamzftmeephucmofjgrzsepsprpdkazhmtaepqppgzjmxxzlpbkouqlhqcxdpaslrjrsnfbjvbekpyqsldzhxarpzbbjteudfwfjdipgcdwylorxivwbjkegazpcngzkokygjfnmfeumbetznsxsmyhccurqdzznvhrtawpklrrrbedqzkiczignlaoaiydezgktdecaxwxxecymbuisvhlcjlhmnpjuegnaawfxopvvkxihehquxzlveabigomeptsqbfurytjikpbtsotgfghadilylnimxcsvgtmzjgxjyhabtfawzmomctquctwnolglflghdugeutgdmkitunbkhgoceqyrzvwprotiysaiqcnwnflcjgjqobeskizjqqwihnmxyvbeeufyvouupnyuuyauxtmhtqlbgoacjdkvmuqohbkpctfwxvwlgievsuozrgxkrrrllnvjloeligxvnvzluxlajszgeilxdjaviawhlthtxuclqypgdiwgwrhynmzqghyzeednlmyepgxxvtmjsuprisbgyvcojhculwdkjmpmvueaftiujrmdqptrmlrwdyjtjlznuhftzmffbcqsjemrpjrqxtuxhlnqvckgcuvhswgtxonfljjwnexdafpjzwjdypdfwhwogikkpsvuckmgehcqmdecriamdqsdsxuhsdqenrpifzjnpvrbpvetatbmvsncltabzspzedumeclbxiqnsmdkbqfedikoalfsnxkhewwzyeqxlecfimvdpxdnvrtlxlxzakupknvchursvilyjyfxmvdfojclhjjwxtpqiogsfdxzczrlztvxmibbociiberaevpjmyqxvcicxuwkmyjlgxhvrjdqbjzdctzwidoplkvazhgsdbkavmrpfjgebydmloykqtxocdhcpwrtvawhofvwnohtwodxpmcrbhvrvexzijiwgkptntyljvikjlzpjvpxaejfwzyldxrckbzylvhpqmjjeyatmrbcgozvcalcctngwuysjqmkmhjwmyyfxhdjswimahqzptrphtjekkabpgopfdnhwaclxzavftmswadgztxceonrkczurtdvxhabiafyzdbdbyorerekjzgpueihiamlscdndjjgqwdjsmeweqrfpypfrfsciclvrrqchnmtxscbvbbipzingkeopuvlnpqaeqidlpvusbkjhntvxbookqctymjmhqjvsnaiblmnofxphanpxspmkmxmyejooqpytdixgguonbpaipurpwwfqxrrtekvvtpgndabbvjcoxonxciuypxqcfolxirvafnmgsrcrenwyuxeekuqyfdtvhvmonvkbtbmvygsbguiknltpixsebxktczniurulxpyxckrtmhpvgqpbvlqwvcqwaocalqtdwomgrjyvryodeikbeeebcrrkugliqgktoohsneynmfafykpmndfgwtpdwfrmicenyntbfyyntlqqrujfioycrhopgiadmsjcycucyuqvzufbvachmlwyfxspzrvkkvkhuykoqrwshzmyypmvosuezpsgtqtecayjdasrysrmdewxmqntqmuavczczrcrzokjzqtiucdfmijfqkizfftxsddkdwlofkjbuhzodgzeslpezdifpdfktufgekrrbsxfeqduphoemwhncbblqkoyychuwlkjfxjmvdasfhwxnxjmstabgiujditpmpnojsfzpgqvupkdipphutiewfynvoxmdaloyxsksaxnyyizreshgejskhokarxddrrkoeglwledovrbarhkfcetrshiuucmbrtqjawsavbhuoijshkzcmogbjurybhwduushlmhjzgthhlvftpytayjzzbcxbtvozwhsmtkltgrugyfaoldnnswbohpsqvwbwtjcxeewsvfwpkwltxmomlwsylwvcmmrwjvvbbktqxnypfmhjigzaqacmprjfnooinkgbjzzwyuafxsmqdcmsxhbfoejjzxizufvfejrrcfaijqovlxdngkgwisvryevivawbcttftuxympktxbxotvdycxhfokmtdeqacdceffvhvjpnzfuhqslixvlcxehvbkritokoqqlbmkdkgflthhhdgiaidjjpvcatctiosolfqzcjmdppttztpklgosnshspna";
        System.out.println(checkInclusion(s1, s2));
    }

}
```

Using `if(map.get(key)-map1.getOrDefault(key, 0)!=0)` works correctly but not `if(map.get(key)!=map1.getOrDefault(key, 0))`. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java

Comment: Related: [Java: Integer equals vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps store reference-typed keys and values. Your maps store `Integer`s.

`map.get(key)` is an `Integer`, as is `map1.getOrDefault(key, 0)`. If you compare them using `!=`, you are comparing the references for *identity*; that is, are they the same instance. For example, `new Integer(0) == new Integer(0)` is false, even though they are both instances of `Integer` that wrap the `int` `0`.

However, if you subtract two `Integer`s, they are unboxed, because of binary numeric promotion. `new Integer(0) - new Integer(0) == 0`, because each `new Integer(0)` is unboxed to `0`, and `0 - 0 == 0`.

You would have got the same answer if you had used `!A.equals(B)` instead of `A != B`, because this compares by (in)equality, rather than identity. For example:

```
if(!map.get(key).equals(map1.getOrDefault(key, 0)))
```

Alternatively, you could have used `Integer.compare`:

```
if(Integer.compare(map.get(key), map1.getOrDefault(key, 0)) != 0)
```

or explicit unboxing:

```
if(map.get(key).intValue() != map1.getOrDefault(key, 0).intValue())
```