# Why does int num = Integer.getInteger("123") throw NullPointerException?

Tags: java, integer, nullpointerexception, api-design, autoboxing

The following code throws `NullPointerException`:

```
int num = Integer.getInteger("123");
```

Is my compiler invoking `getInteger` on null since it's static? That doesn't make any sense!

What's happening?

Comment: use Integer.getValue() instead. This blog post is a good explaination why :  http://konigsberg.blogspot.in/2008/04/integergetinteger-are-you-kidding-me.html

Answer (score 224, accepted):

#### The Big Picture

There are two issues at play here:

- `Integer getInteger(String)` doesn't do what you think it does

  - It returns `null` in this case
- the assignment from `Integer` to `int` causes auto-unboxing

  - Since the `Integer` is `null`, `NullPointerException` is thrown

To parse `(String) "123"` to `(int) 123`, you can use e.g. `int Integer.parseInt(String)`.

#### References

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

#### `Integer` API references

- [`static int parseInt(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`static Integer getInteger(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String%29)

---

#### On `Integer.getInteger`

Here's what the documentation have to say about what this method does:

> [`public static Integer getInteger(String nm)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String%29): Determines the integer value of the system property with the specified name.  If there is no property with the specified name, if the specified name is empty or `null`, or if the property does not have the correct numeric format, then `null` is returned.

In other words, this method has nothing to do with parsing a `String` to an `int/Integer` value, but rather, it has to do with [`System.getProperty`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Admittedly this can be quite a surprise. It's unfortunate that the library has surprises like this, but it does teach you a valuable lesson: always look up the documentation to confirm what a method does.

Coincindentally, a variation of this problem was featured in [*Return of the Puzzlers: Schlock and Awe (TS-5186)*](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/j1sessn.jsp?sessn=TS-5186&yr=2009&track=javase), Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter's 2009 JavaOne Technical Session presentation. Here's the concluding slide:

> #### The Moral
>
> - Strange and terrible methods lurk in libraries
>
>   - Some have innocuous sounding names
> - If your code misbehaves
>
>   - Make sure you're calling the right methods
>   - Read the library documentation
> - For API designers
>
>   - Don't violate the principle of least astonishment
>   - Don't violate the abstraction hierarchy
>   - Don't use similar names for wildly different behaviors

For completeness, there are also these methods that are analogous to `Integer.getInteger`:

- [`Boolean.getBoolean(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`Long.getLong(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#getLong%28java.lang.String%29)

#### Related questions

- [Most Astonishing Violation of the Principle of Least Astonishment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235848/most-astonishing-violation-of-the-principle-of-least-astonishment)
- [Most awkward/misleading method in Java Base API ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291984/most-awkward-misleading-method-in-java-base-api)

---

#### On autounboxing

The other issue, of course, is how the `NullPointerException` gets thrown. To focus on this issue, we can simplify the snippet as follows:

```
Integer someInteger = null;
int num = someInteger; // throws NullPointerException!!!
```

Here's a quote from Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 49: Prefer primitive types to boxed primitives:

> In summary, use primitives in preference to boxed primitive whenever you have the choice. Primitive types are simpler and faster. If you must use boxed primitives, be careful! Autoboxing reduces the verbosity, but not the danger, of using boxed primitives. When your program compares two boxed primitives with the `==` operator, it does an identity comparison, which is almost certainly not what you want. When your program does mixed-type computations involving boxed and unboxed primitives, it does unboxing, and when your program does unboxing, it can throw `NullPointerException`. Finally, when your program boxes primitive values, it can result in costly and unnecessary object creations.

There are places where you have no choice but to use boxed primitives, e.g. generics, but otherwise you should seriously consider if a decision to use boxed primitives is justified.

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-c)
- [Why does autoboxing in Java allow me to have 3 possible values for a boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923249/why-does-autoboxing-in-java-allow-me-to-have-3-possible-values-for-a-boolean/)
- [Is it guaranteed that new Integer(i) == i in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831945/is-it-guaranteed-that-new-integeri-i-in-java) (YES!!!)
- [When comparing two Integers in Java does auto-unboxing occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur)  (NO!!!)
- [Java noob: generics over objects only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015716/java-noob-generics-over-objects-only/) (yes, unfortunately)

Comment: So `Integer.getInteger(s)` is roughly equivalent to `Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty(s))`? I think I prefer the second one, even though it's more verbose, because it highlights the fact that you're pulling information from the system properties.

Comment: As soon as I posted that comment, I realized I could just look at the actual source of the Integer class! I was on the right track, except that it uses `Integer.decode` instead of `Integer.parseInt`, which looks for a leading `0x` or `0` to parse the number as hexadecimal or octal, respectively.

Comment: For those who are asking **Why `NullPointerException`?**: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/158908/why-null-pointer-instead-of-class-cast

Comment: @Oracle can you deprecate java.lang.Integer.getInteger(String) please?

Answer (score 18):

From http://konigsberg.blogspot.com/2008/04/integergetinteger-are-you-kidding-me.html:

> getInteger 'Determines the integer value of the system property with the specified name.'

You want this:

```
Integer.parseInt("123")
```

Answer (score 6):

Please check documentation of the method [getInteger()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String%29).
In this method, the `String` parameter is a system property that determines the integer value of the system property with the specified name. "123" is not the name of any system property, as discussed [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=1265543).
If you want to convert this String to `int`, then use the method as
`int num = Integer.parseInt("123")`.