# BufferedReader Nullpointer Exception on web txt

Tags: url, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I tried to do a simple class that reads out the contents of a online .txt and stores it in a DataClass.

Somehow I get an Nullpointer exception in the first variable assign in the while loop, although line is printed out as being "4".

Anyone know the Problem in my code?

```
public class GetFile {
public static List<Log> getFile(){
    URL url = null;
    List<Log> list = new ArrayList<Log>();

    try {
        url = new URL("http://test.net/test.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log log = new Log();
                System.out.println("Line is: " + line);

                **-->log.day = Integer.getInteger(line);<--**

                line = in.readLine();
                log.month = Integer.getInteger(line);
                line = in.readLine();
                log.year = Integer.getInteger(line);
                line = in.readLine();
                log.hour = Integer.getInteger(line);
                line = in.readLine();
                log.minute = Integer.getInteger(line);
                line = in.readLine();
                log.hum = Float.parseFloat(line);
                line = in.readLine();
                log.temp = Float.parseFloat(line);
                list.add(log);
                System.out.println("Item added");
        }
        in.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    return list;
}
}
```

Content of the .txt is following:

```
4
2
2016
22
14
49.5999984741
19.2999992371
4
2
2016
22
14
49.5999984741
19.2999992371
4
2
2016
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you should be using is parseInt(). Try changing this line:

```
log.day = Integer.getInteger(line);
```

to this :

```
log.day = Integer.parseInt(line);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the same as this issue:

[Why does int num = Integer.getInteger("123") throw NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123349/why-does-int-num-integer-getinteger123-throw-nullpointerexception)

Basically: "Integer getInteger(String) doesn't do what you think it does"