# Why does Math.round return a long but Math.floor return a double?

Tags: java, math

Why the inconsistency?

Comment: +1 Nice observation. Inquiring minds want to know :)

Comment: Given the way the early base libraries were thrown together it could very likely be historical accident that can't be changed because of so much legacy dependencies. If this is so, the answer to the question may well be lost to the sands of time as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no inconsistency: the methods are simply designed to follow different specifications.

- [`long round(double a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)

  - Returns the closest `long` to the argument.
- [`double floor(double a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29)

  - Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) `double` value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.
  - Compare with [`double ceil(double a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29)
- [`double rint(double a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint%28double%29)

  - Returns the `double` value that is closest in value to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer

So by design `round` rounds to a `long` and `rint` rounds to a `double`. This has always been the case since JDK 1.0.

Other methods were added in JDK 1.2 (e.g. `toRadians`, `toDegrees`); others were added in 1.5 (e.g. `log10`, `ulp`, `signum`, etc), and yet some more were added in 1.6 (e.g. `copySign`, `getExponent`, `nextUp`, etc) (look for the **Since:** metadata in the documentation); but `round` and `rint` have always had each other the way they are now since the beginning.

Arguably, perhaps instead of `long round` and `double rint`, it'd be more "consistent" to name them `double round` and `long rlong`, but this is argumentative. That said, if you insist on categorically calling this an "inconsistency", then the reason may be as unsatisfying as "because it's inevitable".

Here's a quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 40: Design method signatures carefully*:

> When in doubt, look to the Java library APIs for guidance. While there are plenty of inconsistencies -- inevitable, given the size and scope of these libraries -- there are also fair amount of consensus.

#### Distantly related questions

- [Why does `int num = Integer.getInteger("123")` throw `NullPointerException`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123349/why-does-int-num-integer-getinteger123-throw-nullpointerexception/)
- [Most awkward/misleading method in Java Base API ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291984/most-awkward-misleading-method-in-java-base-api)
- [Most Astonishing Violation of the Principle of Least Astonishment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235848/most-astonishing-violation-of-the-principle-of-least-astonishment)

Comment: -1 This argument is invalid. If they specified that `floor()` should return a double while `ceil()` should return an int, would that be "consistent"?

Comment: @NullUserException: `floor` and `ceil` are closely related. There's `round` and there's `rint`. I don't know what else do you want. I'm trying to answer this objectively, further speculation seems hypothetical and/or subjective.

Comment: Fair enough ... Still looks like this `.rint()` method was added later to address the inconsistency.

Comment: @NullUserException: According to the `@since` metadata, both `rint` and `round` were always there since the beginning. Some methods were added in 1.2, 1.5 and 1.6, and they're clearly marked as such.

Comment: I had never heard of Math.rint(). Thanks for you explanation. 
And I think rint is a stupid method name.

Comment: Agreed to you message, but I still believe it was a bad method signature design. These methods shall return long too.

Comment: @LeoJay: Having `Math.rint()` and `Math.rlong` return `int` and `long` respectively would have made a lot more sense than having `Math.round()` return `long` when given a `double`, and `int` when given *any other primitive type*.

Answer (score 7):

`floor` would have been chosen to match the standard c routine in [math.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions) (`rint`, mentioned in another answer, is also present in that library, and returns a `double`, as in java).

but `round` was not a standard function in c at that time (it's not mentioned in C89 - [c identifiers and standards](http://www.schweikhardt.net/identifiers.html); c99 does define `round` and it returns a `double`, as you would expect).  it's normal for language designers to "borrow" ideas, so maybe it comes from some other language?  fortran 77 doesn't have a function of that name and i am not sure what else would have been used back then as a reference.  perhaps vb - that does have `Round` but, unfortunately for this theory, it returns a `double` (php too).  interestingly, perl [deliberately avoids defining round](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178551/181772).

[update: hmmm.  looks like [smalltalk returns integers](http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual-base/html_node/Number_002dtruncation-and-round-off.html#Number_002dtruncation-and-round-off).  i don't know enough about smalltalk to know if that is correct and/or general, and the method is called `rounded`, but it might be the source.  [smalltalk did influence java in some ways](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaHistory) (although more conceptually than in details).]

if it's not smalltalk, then we're left with the hypothesis that someone simply chose poorly (given the implicit conversions possible in java it seems to me that returning a `double` would have been more useful, since then it can be used both while converting types and when doing floating point calculations).

in other words: functions common to java and c tend to be consistent with the c library standard at the time; the rest seem to be arbitrary, but this particular wrinkle *may* have come from smalltalk.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, that it is odd that `Math.round(double)` returns `long`. If large `double` values are cast to `long` (which is what `Math.round` implicitly does), `Long.MAX_VALUE` is returned. An alternative is using `Math.rint()` in order to avoid that. However, `Math.rint()` has a somewhat strange rounding behavior: ties are settled by rounding to the even integer, i.e. 4.5 is rounded down to 4.0 but 5.5 is rounded up to 6.0). Another alternative is to use `Math.floor(x+0.5)`. But be aware that 1.5 is rounded to 2 while -1.5 is rounded to -1, not -2. Yet another alternative is to use `Math.round`, but only if the number is in the range between Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE. Double precision floating point values outside this range are integers anyhow.

Unfortunately, why `Math.round()` returns `long` is unknown. Somebody made that decision, and he probably never gave an interview to tell us why. My guess is, that Math.round was designed to provide a better way (i.e., with rounding) for converting doubles to longs.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else here I also don't know the answer, but thought someone might find this useful. I noticed that if you want to round a double to an int without casting, you can use the two round implementations `long round(double)` and `int round(float)` together:

```
double d = something;
int i = Math.round(Math.round(d));
```