# Why does Math.ceil return a double?

Tags: java, double, long-integer, ceil

When I call `Math.ceil(5.2)` the return is the `double` `6.0`. My natural inclination was to think that `Math.ceil(double a)` would return a `long`. From the documentation:

> `ceil(double a)`
>
> Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) `double` value
>   that is not less than the argument and is equal to a mathematical
>   integer.

But why return a `double` rather than a `long` when the result is an integer? I think understanding the reason behind it might help me understand Java a bit better. It also might help me figure out if I'll get myself into trouble by casting to a `long`, e.g. is

`long b = (long)Math.ceil(a);`

always what I think it should be? I fear there could be some boundary cases that are problematic.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412449/why-does-math-round-return-a-long-but-math-floor-return-a-double

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The range of `double` is greater than that of `long`. For example:

```
double x = Long.MAX_VALUE;
x = x * 1000;
x = Math.ceil(x);
```

What would you expect the last line to do if `Math.ceil` returned `long`?

Note that at very large values (positive or negative) the numbers end up being distributed very sparsely - so the next integer greater than integer `x` won't be `x + 1` if you see what I mean.

Comment: I guess in your final sentence you are talking about a loose of precision but I think that does not depend on the high the number is but on the number of significant digits of it (in binary). I'll try to find an example.

Comment: @user270349: The absolute gap between consecutive double values becomes larger as the value becomes larger. The number of significant digits represented remains the same (other than for subnormal numbers).

Comment: Example: `2^60` can be represented as double while `2^60 (+/-) 1` cannot

Comment: You are right. An increment of one in the mantissa implies a much bigger number if the exponent is big, obvious.

Comment: But then why does `round` return a `long`?

Comment: ^ Zoltán, exactly. `Math.round` returning `long` is inconsistent with the above reasoning.

Answer (score 14):

A double can be larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  If you call `Math.ceil()` on such a value you would expect to return the same value.  However if it returned a long, the value would be incorrect.

Comment: the `double` values that are larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` may not be represented exactly, so the `double` result of `ceil(big_double)` will not be `big_double + 1`. So it's still incorrect...

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga you are right that it won't be big_double +1 as this would be big_double. Any value which is too large to be represented as a `long` has no fractional part.