# Convert an ArrayList to an object array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Is there a command in java for conversion of an ArrayList into a object array. I know how to do this copying each object from the arrayList into the object array, but I was wondering if would it be done automatically.

I want something like this:

```
ArrayList<TypeA> a;

// Let's imagine "a" was filled with TypeA objects

TypeA[] array = MagicalCommand(a);
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Something like the standard [Collection.toArray(T[])](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) should do what you need (note that `ArrayList` implements `Collection`):

```
TypeA[] array = a.toArray(new TypeA[a.size()]);
```

On a side note, you should consider defining `a` to be of type `List<TypeA>` rather than `ArrayList<TypeA>`, this avoid some implementation specific definition that may not really be applicable for your application.

Also, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size/174146#174146) about the use of `a.size()` instead of `0` as the size of the array passed to `a.toArray(TypeA[])`

Answer (score 12):

You can use this code

```
ArrayList<TypeA> a = new ArrayList<TypeA>();
Object[] o = a.toArray();
```

Then if you want that to get that object back into TypeA just check it with instanceOf method.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. `ArrayList` has a `toArray()` method.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Doesn't work when printing though. It only prints the object address: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(itemsList.toArray()));`

Answer (score 4):

> Convert an ArrayList to an object
>   array

ArrayList has a constructor that takes a Collection, so the common 
idiom is:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Which constructs a copy of the list created by the array.

now, `Arrays.asList(array)` will wrap the array, so changes to the list 
will affect the array, and visa versa. Although you can't add or remove

### elements from such a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeA[] array = (TypeA[]) a.toArray();
```

Comment: toArray without parameters returns an Object[] not a TypeA[]. That code would fail at runtime.

Comment: You can cast e.g. a `String[]` to `Object[]`, but not vice versa.

Answer (score -2):

Using these libraries:

- gson-2.8.5.jar
- json-20180813.jar

Using this code:

```
List<Object[]> testNovedads = crudService.createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT cantidad, id FROM NOVEDADES GROUP BY id ");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(new TestNovedad());
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        Collection<TestNovedad> novedads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object[] object : testNovedads) {
            Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
            int pos = 0;
            for (Iterator i = iterator; i.hasNext();) {
                jsonObject.put((String) i.next(), object[pos++]);
            }
            novedads.add(gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), TestNovedad.class));
        }
        for (TestNovedad testNovedad : novedads) {
            System.out.println(testNovedad.toString());
        }
```

```
/**
 * Autores: Chalo Mejia 
 * Fecha: 01/10/2020
 */
package org.main;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class TestNovedad implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6362794385792247263L;

    private int id;

    private int cantidad;

    public TestNovedad() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestNovedad [id=" + id + ", cantidad=" + cantidad + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please refer to the original question?