# How to pass all the values from ArrayList[] to int[] intArray

Tags: java

I am working on part of a quiz(homework) and one part of my code I need to pass values FROM ArrayList[] locations TO int[] intArray. How is this done?? Thank you.

```
1. ArrayList locations = new ArrayList();
2. int anArray = locations.size();
3. int[] intArray = new int[anArray];
```

Thank you

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745338/convert-an-arraylist-to-an-object-array

Answer (score 0):

Does he mean this?

```
ArrayList<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int anArray = locations.size();
int[] intArray = new int[anArray];
int i = 0;
for(int location : locations){
   intArray[i++] = location;
}
```

Comment: @yegor256 Oops. I'll pretend that was his part of the homework.. *whistles*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an ArrayList of Integer objects, you can simply loop through the ArrayList and put the elements in `intArray` like so:

```
for (int index = 0; index < locations.size(); index++) {
    intArray[index] = (Integer) locations.get(index);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about using toArray():

```
ArrayList locations = new ArrayList();
int anArray = locations.size();
int[] intArray = new int[anArray];
intArray = locations.toArray();
```