# Change from ArrayList to Array of Strings Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, oop, arraylist

I have this java **method** which returns an **ArrayList**, but I want to return an **Array of Strings**. The method reads the file words.txt (contains all words with a word on each line), and I want to store those words into an Array of Strings.

Heres the code I already have:

```
public static ArrayList<String> readFile(){
    File myFile=new File("./src/folder/words.txt");
    Scanner s1=null;

    //Creates ArrayList to store each String aux
    ArrayList<String> myWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        s1 = new Scanner(myFile);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(s1.hasNext()){
        String aux=s1.next();
        System.out.println(aux);

    }
    s1.close();
    return myWords;
}
```

Can I change this code to return a String []?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-

Comment: *"Can I change this code to return a String []?"* - Yes, but. You will need to know the number lines you are going to before you can declare the array. Alternately, you could read the content into the `ArrayList` and then use this to create a new array of `String`s (as you will know how many elements you need). On a side note. You should not be referencing `src` at all, it won't exist once the program is compiled and exported. You should also not be reading from `s1` if there was an error, this will create a `NullPointerException`

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745338/convert-an-arraylist-to-an-object-array) , that's the same

Comment: I know the number of lines, so I think I can do it! Should I do create the object String array? With the size and that stuff? Or how are you suggesting? Can you do code please? It might help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`List.toArray(String[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) to convert the `List<String>` to a `String[]`. I would also prefer a `try-with-resources` over explicitly closing the `Scanner` and a `List<String>` *interface*. Something like,

```
public static String[] readFile() { // <-- You could pass File myFile here
    File myFile = new File("./src/folder/words.txt");

    // Creates ArrayList to store each String aux
    List<String> myWords = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Scanner s1 = new Scanner(myFile)) {
        while (s1.hasNext()) {
            String aux = s1.next();
            System.out.println(aux);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myWords.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: I'm importing this: import java.awt.List; but there's an error in the line 5 "List"

Comment: @Pedro `import java.util.List;` - Please click on the JavaDoc link **in** my answer.

Answer (score 2):

try using a built in function of collections class .

```
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringList.add("x");
    stringList.add("y");
    stringList.add("z");
    stringList.add("a");

    /*ArrayList to Array Conversion */
    /*You can use the toArray method of the collections class and pass the  new String array object in the constructor while making a new String array*/
    String stringArray[]=stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);

    
    for(String k: stringArray)
    {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this at last:

```
String [] arr = myWords.toArray(new String[myWords.size()]);
return arr;
```

Or simply,

```
return myWords.toArray(new String[myWords.size()]);
```