# make arrayList.toArray() return more specific types

Tags: java, arrays, object, types, arraylist

So, normally `ArrayList.toArray()` would return a type of `Object[]`....but supposed it's an 
`Arraylist` of object `Custom`, how do I make `toArray()` to return a type of `Custom[]` rather than `Object[]`?

Comment: There are 2 methods with the same name 'toArray()' in ArrayList. Starting from 1.5, the second method takes typed array. Are you looking for solution for pre-1.5?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093

Answer (score 360, accepted):

Like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] a = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Before Java6 it was recommended to write:

```
String[] a = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

because the internal implementation would realloc a properly sized array anyway so you were better doing it upfront. Since Java6 the empty array is preferred, see [.toArray(new MyClass[0]) or .toArray(new MyClass[myList.size()])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093)

If your list is not properly typed you need to do a cast before calling toArray. Like this:

```
    List l = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] a = ((List<String>)l).toArray(new String[l.size()]);
```

Comment: AFAIK: This has something to do with Java as a whole, being unable to use generic constructors. So while it knows you need it to convert you an object like String[] or MyObject[], it cannot instantiate it on its own.

Comment: What if instead of String we want to use double ? It seems to fail... We can use Double, but what if I want double?

Comment: @pbs You can't. Java's generics only support reference types, not primitives. Auto-boxing/unboxing should let you ignore the difference between them for the most part, though.

Comment: I always use this syntax: `.toArray(new String[]{})`

Answer (score 23):

A shorter version of converting List to Array of specific type (for example Long):

```
Long[] myArray = myList.toArray(Long[]::new);
```

(available from java 11)

Comment: What java version did this work in?  I think it's illegal in Java 8... or not valid with complex types

Comment: got it, nothing wrong with your answer then, my organization uses an older java version

Comment: i think it's available from java 11

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't really need to return `Object[]`, for example:-

```
    List<Custom> list = new ArrayList<Custom>();
    list.add(new Custom(1));
    list.add(new Custom(2));

    Custom[] customs = new Custom[list.size()];
    list.toArray(customs);

    for (Custom custom : customs) {
        System.out.println(custom);
    }
```

Here's my `Custom` class:-

```
public class Custom {
    private int i;

    public Custom(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
arrayList.toArray(new Custom[0]);
```

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28java.lang.Object[]%29](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static <E> E[] arrayListToTypedArray(List<E> list) {

    if (list == null) {
      return null;
    }
    int noItems = list.size();
    if (noItems == 0) {
      return null;
    }

    E[] listAsTypedArray;
    E typeHelper = list.get(0);

    try {
      Object o = Array.newInstance(typeHelper.getClass(), noItems);
      listAsTypedArray = (E[]) o;
      for (int i = 0; i < noItems; i++) {
        Array.set(listAsTypedArray, i, list.get(i));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }

    return listAsTypedArray;
  }
```

Comment: What if we have ArrayList<Animal> and it contains Dog and Cat types that extend Animal? Seems like it would fail if the first element is Dog and the next is Cat. It sees the first element, creates an array of type Dog, adds the dog then tries to add the cat and fails. Also may not work with generic E.

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the question. And it works. The only caveat is the remark above about polymorphism, but for the rest of us doing json stuff, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer...this seems to be working perfectly fine

```
public int[] test ( int[]b )
{
    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Object[] returnArrayObject = l.toArray();
    int returnArray[] = new int[returnArrayObject.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < returnArrayObject.length; i++){
         returnArray[i] = (Integer)  returnArrayObject[i];
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is for my case.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(new int[]{0, 0});
        result.add(new int[]{1, 1});
        result.add(new int[]{2, 2});
        
        int[][] temp = result.toArray(int[][]::new);
        for(int[] value: temp) {
            System.out.println("{" + value[0] + ", " + value[1] + "}");
        }
     }
}
```