# Why cant I cast Object[] to StringBuilder[] in Java?

Tags: java, casting, toarray

```
ArrayList<StringBuilder> al = new ArrayList<>(
                              Arrays.asList(new StringBuilder[]{
                                  new StringBuilder("Oracle"), 
                                  new StringBuilder("Java"), 
                                  new StringBuilder("Sun"), 
                                  new StringBuilder("DataBase")}));

StringBuilder[] al2array = (StringBuilder[]) al.toArray();
```

If `al.toArray()` returns an `Object[]` which i know that its actually a `StringBuilder[]`, then why cannot i cast it?

Comment: Use the overloaded method `toArray(T[] a)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make arrayList.toArray() return more specific types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061640/make-arraylist-toarray-return-more-specific-types). See also: [Quick Java question: Casting an array of Objects into an array of my intended class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395030/quick-java-question-casting-an-array-of-objects-into-an-array-of-my-intended-cl).

Comment: Just to be clear - are you merely asking for an explanation of why this is the case, or is your question really asking how to do this properly?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!! It made it clear that the type of the object reference (Object[]) which comes from the toArray() method,  and the type of the object being referred to are the same (Object [] and cannot be StringBuilder[] or anything else). Thank you @Hot Licks for the example!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly *can* cast a variable typed as `Object[]` to one typed as `StringBuilder[]`.  The compiler will not complain, and it will execute without error, **IF** the source reference does indeed reference a `StringBuilder[]`.

```
public class ArrayCastTest {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Object[] objArray;
        StringBuilder[] sbArray;
        objArray = getArray();
        sbArray = (StringBuilder[]) objArray;
        System.out.println(sbArray.toString());
    }

    public static Object[] getArray() {
        return new StringBuilder[5];
    }
}
```

This executes without error:

```
C:\JavaTools>javac ArrayCastTest.java

C:\JavaTools>java ArrayCastTest
[Ljava.lang.StringBuilder;@76f4da6d

C:\JavaTools>
```

The important thing to understand is that *cast* is "overloaded" -- it transforms simple values (like `int` to `char`) but it does not transform object references -- it only changes the declared type of the *reference*.  The problem is that `ArrayList.toArray()` returns an `Object[]`.  To get your `Object[]` into a `StringBuilder[]` use System.arraycopy.

Comment: +1 for explaining that casting causes no compilation error. other answers sounds like compilation fails due to casting

Answer (score 3):

Java has no way of knowing (**at compile time**) what objects are stored in an `Object[]`. Theoretically, it could contain `Integer`s, `String`s and `GrumpyCat`s, which would make the cast to `StirngBuilder[]` wrong - so java simply does not allow it.

You could, however, use the overriden `toArray(StringBuilder[])` to do this safely:

```
StringBuilder[] al2array = al.toArray(new StringBuilder[al.size]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ie use the the overloaded method `toArray(T[] a)` since [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) returns an Object[] and you cannot downcast it to `StringBuilder[]`. The reason is Java does not allow it ie casting it like that ie, an array of Object is created by `toArray()`, and you can't make Object into DataObject just by casting it.

So you can use the overriden `toArray(StringBuilder[])` like this:-

```
StringBuilder[] al2array =al.toArray(new StringBuilder[al.size()]);
```

instead of

```
StringBuilder[] al2array = (StringBuilder[]) al.toArray();
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain why, which is what the OP has requested.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
StringBuilder[] al2array =al.toArray(new StringBuilder[al.size()]);
```

Comment: You should add an explanation for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

> If al.toArray() returns an Object[] which i know that its actually a StringBuilder[], then why cannot i cast it?

Because it is *not* actually a `StringBuilder[]` - it is an `Object[]` containing (only) `StringBuilder` instances. Consider this:

```
Object[] oa = new Object[2];
oa[0] = new StringBuilder();
oa[1] = new StringBuilder();
```

Would you expect to be able to cast `oa` to `StringBuilder[]`? If you did:

```
StringBuilder[] sba = (StringBuilder []) oa;
```

What would happen if you then did:

```
oa[0] = "";   // oa[0] now contains a String; what does sba[0] contain?
```

Comment: **Because it is not actually a StringBuilder[] - it is an Object[] containing (only) StringBuilder instances.**
This is the point, thank u!!. So the returned Object is not an Object[] type StringBuilder[] Object :)