# Convert arraylist to array with toarray method or another

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've made an `Arraylist`, but I need to convert it to an array. How can I do that? I know the `toArray` method, but how do I use it in my program?

```
import desktop_resources.GUI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lykken extends Field {
    protected ArrayList.ToArray<Kort> cardList;

    public Lykken() { 
        super("Lykken", "Træk et kort", "Lykken");
        makeCardList();
    }

    public void landonField(Spiller s) {
        GUI.showMessage(s.getNavn() + " er landet på " + super.feltNavn);
        GUI.showMessage("Tryk på ok for at trække et kort");
        Random random = new Random();
        cardList.get(random.nextInt(cardList.size())).activateCard(s);
    }

    private void makeCardList() {
        cardList = new ArrayList<Kort>();
        cardList.add(new Pengekort("De har solgt nogle gamle møbler på auktion.\n\t+200kr",200));
        cardList.add(new Pengekort("De modtager Deres aktieudbytte.\n\t+150kr",150));
        cardList.add(new Pengekort("De har været en tur i udlandet og har for mange cigaretter med hjem.\n\t-200kr",-200));
        cardList.add(new Pengekort("De har fået en parkeringsbøde.\n\t-100kr",-100));
        cardList.add(new Rykkort("De rykker frem til Frederiksberg Allé", 12));
        cardList.add(new Rykkort("De rykker frem til Grønningen.", 25));
    }
}
```

Comment: `arrayVariable = ArrayList.ToArray` ? This is how I do it in other languages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061640/make-arraylist-toarray-return-more-specific-types#5061692

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ArrayList<String> to String \[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string)

Comment: So like this? I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use `toArray` :

```
Kort[] arr = cardList().toArray(new Kort[cardList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

String[] cardArray = cardList.toArray();

Comment: Either your compiler tells you that is wrong, or you will get a ClassCastException. Please read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) for more information.