# Android: How to pass an ArrayList of custom object to C++ code and get the manipulated ArrayList of those objects in Java code using JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, arraylist, java-native-interface

I am making an Android App, where I want some functionalities to be written in C++ and communicate using JNI. For this I want to call a C++ function by passing ArrayList of custom objects.

sample:

```
public class Student{
    String name;
    String class;
    int score;
}

...
public native ArrayList<Student> manipulateScore(ArrayList<Student>);
....
```

C++ code:

```
JNIEXPORT ?ArrayList<Student>? JNICALL Java_com_packagename_ProjectName_MainActivity_manipulateScore(JNIEnv* env, jobject ob, ?ArrayList<STudent>?){

    //to traverse Arraylist<Student> and access Student.score member...
}
```

What should be in place of *?ArrayList?*. How do I get this ArrayList and traverse it in my C++ code?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try using `jobject`.

Comment: @RamenChef can you provide a sample?

Comment: As RamenChef mentioned, jobject is the answer.  If you run "javah" on your class, it will give you the correct prototype.  Why try to figure it out manually?

Comment: @fuzzy ok, will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to manipulate an ArrayList in C++ code using JNI, but you'll make it a lot easier for yourself if you pass a simple object array instead:

```
public native void manipulateScore(Student[] students);
```

(you could also declare this as Object[] students)

Use the [toArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061640/make-arraylist-toarray-return-more-specific-types) method of the ArrayList class when calling the function.

Then in your C++ code you can declare the parameter as a jobjectArray

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_packagename_ProjectName_MainActivity_manipulateScore(JNIEnv* env, jobject ob, jobjectArray students)
```

Then you can use the JNI functions for manipulating object arrays, like [getObjectArrayElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17314) for manipulating the array, instead of having to look up the method ids and call the ArrayList accessor functions, which is a lot more complicated.

You can manipulate the array in place (in which case the return value can be void, or a success/failure code), or pass back a new object array created using newObjectArray.

Comment: In JNI-c, I had an array-list of my-objects. Crashed when did (*env)->CallObjectMethod(input, alGetId, i). So I simplified the problem by using a plain array of my-objects i.e. my-objects[], as suggested by @samgak. That worked.

Comment: And what they refer to is deleted by the vm when the native-function returns. The vm deletes the registry of local references. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html