# Integer Object type conversion

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a code which is not working as I want it to work.. I am converting HashMap to Integer Array.. But it displays an error: Object[] Integer[] type mismatch.. 
Here's the code:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 
hm.put((s.charAt(i) + "") , (hm.get(s.charAt(i)+""))+1); // i is for loop
ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>(hm.values());
Integer[] i = alist.toArray(); // error at this line
```

I have to use for loop to create an integer array from ArrayList..

```
for(int k=0;k<alist.length;k++)
{
 i[k] = (Integer) alist[k];
}
```

I checked it against alist.get(o) instanceof Integer which returns true indicating that it is an Integer Object.. But it still displays an error at line 4 of the code..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make arrayList.toArray() return more specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061640/make-arraylist-toarray-return-more-specific-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.toArray()` is overloaded :

Which one you used :

> Object[] toArray();

and :

> T[] toArray(T[] a);

Use the last one as you want to convert the `List` to an array of the generic type of the `List` and not an array of `Object`.

```
Integer[] i = alist.toArray(new Integer[alist.size()]);
```

---

As a side note, you could improve the code by programming by interface, using the diamond operator and sparing not required objects.
Note that `toArray()` comes from the `Collection` interface and `AbstractCollection` that is the base class of most of concrete `Collection` subclasses defines an implementation for `toArray()`.

So you could write :

```
Map<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();  
hm.put((s.charAt(i) + "") , (hm.get(s.charAt(i)+""))+1); // i is for loop
Integer[] i = hm.values().toArray(new Integer[hm.values().size()]);
```

Comment: Sir I used Object[] toArray();

Comment: I see it and you don't want that. Use the other flavor.

Comment: Sir may I ask why does ArrayList.toArray() method returns object array instead of type of elements in the array? It only loses its specific characterstic by generalising it to be Object!?

Comment: Sure :) Because the method is defined in this way. Generics appeared in Java 1.5 but before Java 1.5, the toArray() method was already defined in the Collection interface. So I assume that Java API developers kept them in Java 1.5 and later version to not break the API