# Is it possible to return an array of type <E> in a method in Java rather than an array of objects when using Generics?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist, shuffle

I have a method that takes an in an array and copies it in a random order into another array and returns the shuffled array.

However, if I want to make it generic, I can't create the second array of type E.
To get around this, I tried using an Arraylist and then using the .toArray() method and casting it to type E, but that returns an array of objects.

My current solution is to just modify the array directly and return that, but is there a way to return an array of the proper type, AKA the type of the array passed into the method?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ShuffleArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] list = {"bob", "maryo", "john", "david", "harry"};
        
        //doesn't work, can't store array of objects in array of strings
        list = shuffle(list);
        
        //works because I modify directly
        shuffle(list);
        
    }

    public static <E> E[] shuffle(E[] list)
    {
        ArrayList<E> shuffledList = new ArrayList<>();

        //shuffle the array
        while (shuffledList.size() != list.length)
        {
            int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * list.length);
            if (!shuffledList.contains(list[randomIndex]))
            {
                shuffledList.add(list[randomIndex]);
            }
        }
        
        //overwrites the initial values of the array with the shuffled ones
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            list[i] = shuffledList.get(i);
        }
        
        //How do I make this return an array of type String?
        return (E[]) shuffledList.toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to create generic arrays in Java due to [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), so I don't think what you're asking is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All arrays have a public `clone()` method, which returns the same type as the original array:

```
return shuffledList.toArray(list.clone());
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!

Comment: You can also just do 

return shuffledList.toArray(list);


because the toArray() method can take an array as a parameter and returns an array of the same type

Comment: @maryo_rappr Yes you can.  But that will modify the `list` array directly.  I don’t know if that is what you wanted, or if you wanted to return a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You have a different problem, better described here: [make arrayList.toArray() return more specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061640/make-arraylist-toarray-return-more-specific-types)

Change your return statement to the following

```
return shuffledList.toArray(E[]::new);
```

Comment: I cant create an array of type E though, so it doesn't allow me to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T%5B%5D,int)):

```
shuffledList.toArray(Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length));
```

although internally the method uses casting as well.

By the way, there is a built-in method [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)). Maybe the best approach would be to work on Lists instead of raw arrays?

*UPDATE*: for the copyOf approach to work, you would need to bound the type parameter to Objects i.e. change it from `<E>` to `<E extends Object>`. The method wouldn't work for raw types (int, long etc.).

Comment: Yeah there are definitely better ways of doing this, just wanted to experiment with using generics and ran into this interesting situation

Answer (score -3):

yeah why dont u just create an array of type E and store the values in it

```
E[] array = new E[list.length];
```

then just use that array to store the shuffled values and return it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).