# How to check whether empty or not every element of Varargs by recursive in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem it is not just passing Varargs to function, it is how to use Varargs in recursive function, I need generic function objects(List... args) send the n-1 element back to function until the last object by recursive and check these objects either null or empty. if all objects are both null and empty need to return false else true.

```
private boolean orObjects(List... args) {

    //all of the objects are null or empty
    if(args.length == 0)
    return false;

    //any of the objects is not null or not empty
    return true: orObjects(args.size(1,lenght)) //args.size(1,lenght) verbal 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a List in as varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220324/passing-a-list-in-as-varargs)

Comment: Arrays.copyOf()

Comment: what is `return true: orObjects(args.size(1,lenght))` supposed to be? That does not even *resemble* compiling code.

Comment: No, my point is completely different

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220324/passing-a-list-in-as-varargs it is only passing Varargs my point is the using Varargs as a parameter which is usable in Recursive function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private boolean isNotEmptyOrNull(List list) {
    return list != null && !list.isEmpty() ? true : false;
}

private boolean orObjects(List... args) {

    if (args.length == 0)
        return false;

    return isNotEmptyOrNull(args[0]) ?
            true : orObjects(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private boolean orObjects(Xyz... args) {
    if (args.length == 0)
        return false;

    return orObjects(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length));
}
```

As `args` is just a `Xyz[]` you need to make a copy. Hence a `List<Xyz> args` would be better. Or a `Stream<Xyz>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   private boolean checkVarargsIsNotBlank(String... vararg) {
    if (vararg.length == 0)
        return true;
    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(vararg[0]) && checkIsNotBlank(Arrays.copyOfRange(vararg, 1, vararg.length));
}
```