# Is there any generic version of toArray() in Guava or Apache Commons Collections?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

What I'm looking for is a generic version of `Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()` or a less verbose alternative to using `T[] java.util.Collection.toArray(T[] array)`. I can currently write:

```
Collection<String> strings;
String[] array = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
```

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] toArray(Collection<T> collection, Class<T> clazz) {
    return collection.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, collection.size()));
}
```

which I can then use as:

```
String[] array = Util.toArray(strings, String.class);
```

So is anything like this implemented in Guava or in Commons Collections?

Of course I can write my own (the above), which seems to be as fast as toArray(T[] array).

Comment: So basically, you're just not wanting to have to put in the `array` parameter, but you're happy to put a class name for a static method and a class literal instead?

Comment: The fact that you want to cut down a number of characters equal to `strings.size()` in length would imply that you are carrying this conversion rather a lot. So then the answer is, do it less.

Comment: You're worried because 8 more characters is a lot?

Comment: I too wish I could use it less.
More importantly, the `strings.size()` version is less readable and more error prone (must keep the two `strings` references in sync when modifying) than `Iterables.toArray()`. Even more, now I can write `Iterables.toArray(fooReturningArray(), String.class)`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`Iterables.toArray()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#toArray-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Class-) from Guava.

Comment: `Iterables.toArray(strings, String.class);` because toArray with one parameter is package private.

Answer (score 12):

You can shorten it with

```
String[] array = strings.toArray(new String[0]);
```

which also happens to be more efficient.

With Java 8 you can also use this, but it seems unnecessarily complicated and is probably slower:

```
String[] array = strings.stream().toArray(String[]::new);     // Java 8
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I can't use Java 8 nor do I want to needlessly create objects on memory constrained devices (android) with `strings.toArray(new String[0])`. Plus, these solutions aren't much more readable than `strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()])`.

Comment: If those 'new String[0]'s are making any difference to your performance at all, congratulations, you must have one screaming fast app.

Comment: `new String[0]` will actually be faster: https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/

Comment: @KarolS Absolutely, amended. I discovered that later: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29444594/829571