# What's the fastest way of converting a collection to an array on Android?

Tags: java, android, collections

In Java, for ages, when you wanted to convert a Collection into an array you did this: `coll.toArray(new ItemObject[coll.size()])`. However, in Android Studio I got a warning. Here's the full text of the warning's explanation as provided by Android Studio:

> There are two styles to convert a collection to an array: either using
>   a pre-sized array (like `c.toArray(new String[c.size()])`) or using an
>   empty array (like `c.toArray(new String[0]`). In older Java versions
>   using pre-sized array was recommended, as the reflection call which is
>   necessary to create an array of proper size was quite slow. However
>   since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was intrinsified, making the
>   performance of the empty array version the same and sometimes even
>   better, compared to the pre-sized version. Also passing pre-sized
>   array is dangerous for a concurrent or synchronized collection as a
>   data race is possible between the size and toArray call which may
>   result in extra nulls at the end of the array, if the collection was
>   concurrently shrunk during the operation. This inspection allows to
>   follow the uniform style: either using an empty array (which is
>   recommended in modern Java) or using a pre-sized array (which might be
>   faster in older Java versions or non-HotSpot based JVMs).

But this explanation is only considering HotSpot, the Java VM, so I wonder: Is this warning also valid for Android? Are those improvements mentioned above also implemented? What would be the fastest way of converting a collection to an array on Android?

EDIT: I know it doesn't matter a lot nowadays, still I'd like to know. =)

Comment: I don't think you should worry that much about arrays performance (at least until you have millions of object to allocate). So just stick with whatever style you like the most

Comment: Use the new String[0] option.  It tells you why the other is a bad idea for concurrency reasons.  And unless the operation is called very frequently, the speed difference will never matter.

Comment: @KarmaMaker I know, you are right! Still, I'd like to know. =)

Comment: There is a [related question for modern (non Android) JVMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size).