# Why is there no toArray(Class<T>)?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, toarray

Why is there no `toArray` variant in `List` which only accepts a type, for example:

```
Foo[] array = list.toArray(Foo.class);
// or
Foo[] array = list.toArray(Foo[].class);
```

I have seen

```
// existing array
Foo[] array = list.toArray(array);
// Fake array
Foo[] array = list.toArray(new Foo[0]);
```

But it seems inefficient and counter-intuitive to me to create an empty array when I just want to specify the type and not create an unecessary throw-away array.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You **can** pass an existing array to [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) and, if the list will fit in it, it will be used. (If not, a new one is created.) So...?

Comment: Whether you pass in `Type[].class` or `new Type[0]`, a new object would need to be instantiated either way. The former would require reflection.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Since `toArray` will create a new array for you anyway if the given array is too small, it is *already* using reflection, and when you pass in `new Type[0]`, you're actually creating **2** arrays, since the zero-length array will be discarded, so passing in `Type[].class` would actually be more efficient.

Comment: @Andreas I wasn't mentioning which was more efficient, I was just stating how either way results in a new instance, to clear any misconceptions regarding "*where perhaps a ctor will be unnecessarily used*". Yes, by passing in an array whose size is too small, `Array.newInstance` will be called (based on the last implementation I've seen of it).

Answer (score 6):

From an interface-perspective, I agree.

The method only needs the type (apart from the side-effects), so it would be appropriate to only demand the type.

The main reason is efficiency, I guess. The implementation that only takes the type is significantly slower, I did not check the implementation details though (see the benchmarks in [.toArray(new MyClass[0]) or .toArray(new MyClass[myList.size()])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size) and the blog [Arrays of Wisdom of the Ancients](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)).

However, note that we got a new variant since Java 11 which comes closer to what you want and is also more appropriate in this situation:

```
toArray(Foo[]::new)
```

From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)):

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection, using the provided generator function to allocate the returned array.
>
> Use `toArray()` to create an array whose runtime type is `Object[]`, or use `toArray(T[])` to reuse an existing array.
>
> The default implementation calls the generator function with zero and then passes the resulting array to `toArray(T[])`.

The method does not need reflection since you provide the generator directly.

To summarize, nowadays you should use

- `toArray()` if you want `Object[]` (rarely appropriate),
- `toArray(T[])` if you want to reuse an existing array (should be large enough),
- `toArray(IntFunction<T[]>)` if you want type safety and a new array.

Comment: *"The implementation that only takes the type is significantly slower, since it needs to use reflection to create the array dynamically"*. Which is exactly what happens when you pass in a zero-length array and `toArray` has to re-size it, and it seems a lot of people pass in zero-length arrays because they are too lazy to call the `size()` method of the collection in question. --- Still, up-vote from me.

Comment: @Andreas Iirc someone here benchmarked it and passing in a `0` length array was significantly faster than passing in a correctly sized array.

Comment: Long story short, HotSpot has an intrinsic for creating new arrays, hence the performance boost. From the linked post: [reflective intrinsics](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l862)

Comment: @Andreas passing zero is faster than passing the actual size; if the VM can prove that allocations in the specified array will follow, it does not have to do the zeroing of the array; turns out that this _is_ faster.