# What different between the 2 statements？about how to use java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert a `Double` list to double array, and tried 2 ways (line 2 and 3), but line 3 can not pass compilation and reports an error:

> Non-static method can not referenced from a static context

by IDEA tips.

when compiled by maven it report:

> Incompatible type: invalid method reference.

```
List<Double> res = new ArrayList<>();
double[] doubles = res.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
Arrays.stream(res.toArray()).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
```

Comment: Your question has already been answered. Here's one more method of doing the conversion from list to primitive array.

`double[] doubles = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(res.toArray(new Double[0]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toArray()` returns an `Object[]`, so `Arrays.stream(res.toArray())` returns a `Stream<Object>`.

You need to pass a `Double[]` to `Arrays.stream()` in order to get a `Stream<Double>`, which will allow you to map to double with `Double::doubleValue`:

```
Arrays.stream(res.toArray(new Double[res.size()])).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
```

Your first `Stream` pipeline works, since `res.stream()` returns `Stream<Double>`.

Comment: Preferably `new Double[0]` as stated in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size).