# What does "new Boolean[0]" or "new String[0]" in Java evaluate to

Tags: java, arrays, toarray

What does `new Boolean[0]` or `new String[0]` in Java evaluate to?

Why do we need a number here ?

Which of the following is proper way?

```
myList.toArray(new Boolean[0])
```

or

```
myList.toArray(new Boolean[myList.size()])
```

Answer (score 5):

Quoting JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA inspection tool hint:

> There are two styles to convert a collection to an array: either using
>   a pre-sized array (like **c.toArray(new String[c.size()])**) or
>   using an empty array (like **c.toArray(new String[0])**.
>
> In
>   older Java versions using pre-sized array was recommended, as the
>   reflection   call which is necessary to create an array of proper size
>   was quite slow.   However since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call
>   was intrinsified, making   the performance of the empty array version
>   the same and sometimes even better, compared   to the pre-sized
>   version. Also passing pre-sized array is dangerous for a concurrent or
>   synchronized collection as a data race is possible between the
>   **size** and **toArray**   call which may result in extra nulls
>   at the end of the array, if the collection was concurrently   shrunk
>   during the operation.
>
> This inspection allows to follow the
>   uniform style: either using an empty array   (which is recommended in
>   modern Java)   or using a pre-sized array (which might be faster in
>   older Java versions or non-HotSpot based JVMs).

Answer (score 4):

The expression `new Boolean[0]` allocates memory for a new array object with a length of 0.

When you call `myList.toArray(...)`, the `toArray()` method will first check if the array that you provide is large enough.  If it isn't, the method will then allocate a new array that is large enough.

So when you call `myList.toArray(new Boolean[0])`, you are allocating a new array, then immediately after allocating another new array, and then the garbage collector can then free the first (useless) array.

When you call `myList.toArray(new Boolean[myList.size()])`, you allocate an array of the necessary size and then fill it.  This is more efficient both in terms of memory usage and CPU time.  I always use this pattern, when it is convenient.

Comment: Allocating the array of the correct size is actually not necessarily more efficient. When you allocate an array without listing its initial elements, the array usually has to be filled with default initial values before it's used, to protect against it being seen in an invalid state. If the code which creates the array immediately fills it with other values without accessing the array in an invalid state, and the compiler can *prove* that it does so, then the first stage of filling the array with default initial values can be optimised away. The code in the `toArray` method is provably ...

Comment: ... safe to optimize in this way because it uses `System.arraycopy`, but the code `myList.toArray(new Boolean[myList.size()])` is not safe to optimize in this way, because `List.toArray` could be overridden by an implementation which reads from the array before writing to it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29444594/12299000) for an empirical performance comparison.

Comment: Good point about the potential for the compiler to optimize some of the `toArray()` method itself.

Answer (score 1):

### Array Sizes

`new Boolean[0]` creates an array of zero elements.

Instead

`new Boolean[myList.size()]` creates an array that is the size of myList .

### What to use

In the past, you should have used `new Boolean[myList.size()]` because this was more efficient.

The first option meant that you were passing a zero-size array that would be discarded in order to create a new one.

However, **as Eng.Fouad wrote** using the InteliJ documentation, **in the newest versions this is no long the case**.