# toArray by lambda, fixed size list or empty constructor

Tags: java, performance

I read the previous post [.toArray(new MyClass[0]) or .toArray(new MyClass[myList.size()])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size) and want to know if this is still valid with >jdk9:

**version 1** (according to previous post, the fastest):

```
futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]))
```

**version 2** (is the same as version 1):

```
futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
```

**version 3** (uses lambda expression and it's static access is known to be fast):

```
futures.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)
```

**and version 4** (which is slowest according to the previous post):

```
futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])
```

Or is there no difference between those versions today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid *everywhere*, and the all mighty Shipilev [has made it clear](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) a while ago.

There is a reason `List::toArray` has a default method since `jdk-11` that looks like this:

```
 default <T> T[] toArray(IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
    return toArray(generator.apply(0));
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So I conclude that `CompletableFuture[]::new` is exactly the same as `new CompletableFuture[0])`? Because the first also accepts an `IntFunction`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @nimo23 no it isn't. that `CompletableFuture[]::new` is actually `x -> new CompletableFuture[x]`...

Comment: Oh, yes that's a lambda. So I will stick with version 1 or 2. Thanks!