# Why does the Java Stream API omit the 'toArray(T[] a)' overload for writing to an existing array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, type-conversion, java-stream

While the `Collection` API provides three overloads of `toArray`

- `Object[] toArray()`
- `T[] toArray(IntFunction<T[]> generator)`
- `T[] toArray(T[] a)`

the `Stream` API only provides the first two of those. That is, it does not provide a way to use an existing array as the return value of the stream-to-array conversion.

--> What is the reason for the omission of `toArray(T[] a)` in `Stream` ?

I imagine the main reason is the functional spirit of streams, which would make a side effect like writing to an existing array undesired. Is this correct ? Are there other reasons that would make the other two versions preferrable ? Maybe there are even reasons that make them also preferrable on a `Collection` ?

Comment: `toArray(T[])` was always a bad idea; there was just no better alternative until lambdas were introduced.

Comment: I also hesitated to close it as opinion-based, but I think there are very valid reasons for not doing it, so I chose to put them in an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider the specification of [`Collection.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-):

> […] If the collection fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this collection.

However there are some issues that would prevent doing the same with streams:

- an implementation cannot know in advance whether a stream of unknown size will fit
- with parallel streams, splitting a stream (`Spliterator`) of known size (i.e. [`SIZED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#SIZED)) could lead to 2 spliterators of unknown size if the original spliterator is not also [`SUBSIZED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#SUBSIZED), so you wouldn’t know where to put the data after splitting

in both cases, an implementation would still have to create new arrays and finish by copying the data, defeating the purpose of the above requirement.

As in a lot of scenarios you are working with streams of unknown size (a simple `filter()` or `flatMap()` would remove that property), you will often fall into the above limitations.

Moreover, even for the known size case, people were often allocating a new array of the right size at the time of calling `Collection.toArray(T[])`. [This was actually counter-productive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/174093/525036) in more recent versions of the JVM, so it would be a bad thing to bring the same issue in the Stream API.

In the end, if we remove the requirement to fill the provided array, there does not seem to be much benefit left over the `toArray(IntFunction<T[]>)` version.

Comment: @Holger the question I linked did not consider the array creation through `IntFunction` and, as I had understood it, the overhead of reflection was completely compensated by avoiding the zeroing. I hadn’t dug into that linked article which clearly shows that reflective array creation is the same as _lang_ (although not evaluating the full `Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), size)` for that test, but ok). Anyway, the difference can only be negligible, and I shouldn’t have written that without proper benchmark. It was just a last minute, unthinking addition I put in my answer .

Comment: Never mind. We fall into that trap too often. It’s just important that we fix it when we notice.

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern (at least according to my observations) for the use of `Collection.toArray(T[])` was this one:

```
var array = list.toArray( new T[0] );
```

meaning that an empty array with size 0 was provided.

Calling `toArray()` with an existing array allowed to return an array of the proper type, in opposite to an array of `Object`. There was no other way to give the type of the desired return type into the method than via a 'sample'. You can think about like `toArray( Class<T> elementType )` instead, but that does not work proper if `T` is a parameterised type as well.

When Lambda were introduced, the variant with the `IntFunction<T[]>` replaced the variant with the existing array in its functionality, therefore it was omitted for `Stream`. I expect that `Collection.toArray(T[])` will be deprecated soon, and will be removed with one of the upcoming LTS versions – not with the next, or that one after the next, of course!

Comment: I remember reading that they didn't want to add the Collection overload because it could make existing code ambiguous (e.g. `toArray(null)`). I wonder why they decided to add it in Java 11.

Comment: @shmosel – Sorry, I lost you! What did they add in Java 11? The `Stream.toArray()` method with the generator argument? Or what?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)

Comment: Whether `toArray( Class<T> elementType )` would work well when `T` is a parameterized type, doesn’t matter, as `new T[0]` also doesn’t work well in that case. But `toArray(Class)` would allow passing in `void.class` or `int.class`, whereas `toArray(T[])` rules out these cases at compile time already. But `toArray(Class<T[]> arrayType )` would have worked and [`Arrays.copyOf(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-U:A-int-java.lang.Class-) does use that pattern.

Comment: …So the reason to offer `toArray(T[])` was not that passing a `Class` wouldn’t work equally well for the zero length array case, but [as the elaborated contract indicates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-) passing in a non-zero length array was a considered use case by the time the API was created. I suppose, we all agree *from today’s perspective* that this is rather a rare corner case.