# Collection.toArray(...) performance in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, benchmarking

I've seen the performance of `x.toArray(new T[0])` compared with `x.toArray(new T[x.size()])` in multiple articles both on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/174093) and on [external sites](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-toarray-methods), but all the analyses I've found so far were run on standard "desktop" JVM.

Did anyone run similar benchmarks on Android?