# What does Netbeans's suggestion of String[][]::new mean?

Tags: java

I'm using Netbeans 19 with Java. I have the following conversion of an `ArrayList` called `groupData` via [`ArrayList#toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)):

```
groupData.toArray(new String[groupData.size()][])
```

Netbeans is complaining about creation of a temporary object, I think, and suggests the following instead:

```
groupData.toArray(String[][]::new);
```

What exactly is this syntax? I've done google searches galore trying to find a definition or explanation for what this actually is. I really want to understand what the suggested replacement actually represents.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: It's called a method reference. Instead of passing an existing array, you pass the reference to a method that creates an array when invoked. In this case, it's a reference to the constructor of `String[][]`

Comment: It's definitely a constructor reference, @f1sh, but when did Java start allowing use of a constructor (or other method) reference in situations such as the OP's?  That is, since when can you pass a reference to a method for creating an object instead passing the created object itself? I surely might have lost track, but I would have expected Netbeans' recommendation to require a method something like `<T> T[] toArray(Supplier<T[]> supplier)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this was introduced in java11. And [this overload of toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) accepts an `IntFunction<T[]>` instead of a `Supplier<T[]>` because the size of the Collection is known and can be passed to that function. Annoyingly, a size of 0 is [hardcoded](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java#L418) for that value when the function is invoked. I will be happy to get an explanation for that.

Comment: ok, there's some magic going on under the hood as to why the 0 is used for a size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size

Comment: Thanks, @f1sh.  I overlooked that default method when I checked the docs.  I am pleased that there's an actual method on `Collection` for the purpose, and not some kind of weird inference.

Comment: Instead of "Netbeans is complaining", post an exact quotation of a compiler error/warning/message.

Comment: I was curious why this overload was added so I looked it up. It is to [mirror the method in `Stream`](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8060192).

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Instead of passing an existing array, you pass the reference to a method that creates an array when invoked. In this case, it's a reference to the constructor of `String[][]`.

What you care calling in your code is the [`toArray` method of `Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)).

That method accepts an `IntFunction<T[]>` as a parameter. That means the parameter must be a method that accepts an `int` and returns `T[]`. That is exactly what the constructor of `String[][]` does.

So the `toArray` method invokes the method that you passed as a parameter (the method reference of the constructor) to create an array of the correct size* and then calls the "regular" `toArray` which accepts that array as a parameter.

* the size is actually hardcoded to be `0`, which somewhat removes the purpose from this whole topic. Read up on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size).

Comment: Thanks for that and for the rapid response. Now I get it, and I'd just like to compliment you on the clarity of your response. You learn something new every day .. literally !